# What is the $ symbol used for in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am a JavaScript learner and have been researching this matter, but with no success.  What is the `$` symbol used for in JavaScript besides regular expressions?  Any resources or readings regarding this would be appreciated.  *Thanks*.

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/205853/why-would-a-javascript-variable-start-with-a-dollar-sign

Comment: Perhaps you'll find this thread helpful.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/846585/can-someone-explain-the-dollar-sign-in-javascript

Answer (score 61, accepted):

It doesn't mean anything special.

But because `$` is allowed in identifier names, many Javascript libraries have taken to using `$` as the "central" interface to them, or at least as a shortcut for accessing their functionality.

For example, if you're using jQuery and you say `$("div")`, this is a call to the `$` function with argument "div". When you say `$.post()`, it's calling the `post` method on the `$` object (Javascript is nice in that functions are first-class objects).

Comment: The $ was actually included in the ECMA specification to distinguish machine generated code from human code .

Comment: I originally had this question as well.  $ is a valid variable name as per the the Javascript Specification.... see MDN (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Grammar_and_Types)   So the reason the nebie javascript developer has a problem understanding what $ is, is because you never get to see that $ was assigned as an object or function.  Usually a base object as this answer describes.  i.e. var $ = {}.   If you drill down in the source code of the imported modules you'd eventually find it.

Answer (score 25):

I became acquainted with it in JavaScript when I started using the Prototype framework. In Prototype, `$` is simply the name of an often used function (very, very much simplified - a short for `document.getElementById`). Personally, I like the terseness of it.

Afaik, it's not used for anything by the language itself.

For what it's worth, [Douglas Crockford](http://javascript.crockford.com/code.html) advises against using `$` in the variable/function names **you** write:

> Do not use $ (dollar sign) or \
>   (backslash) in names.

---

Adding another, rather opinionated, quote from Mr. Crockford's talk "[And Then There Was JavaScript](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/theater/video.php?v=crockonjs-2)":

> Dollar sign was added to the language
>   specifically for use by code
>   generators and macro processes, so if
>   you have machines writing code then
>   the machines need to be confident that
>   the variables that they create will
>   not conflict with variables that the
>   humans are going to create. To
>   distinguish them, we’ll allow the
>   machines to use dollar sign. Some of
>   the ninjas found out about that and
>   thought oh, dollar sign, I can use
>   dollar sign as a function name, so
>   they’re out there doing that. And it
>   looks stupid. I mean, look at a
>   program with dollar sign.

Comment: So is `$("someId")` the same as `document.getElementById("someId")` ?

Comment: It's that - and more, in Prototype.

Comment: @Babiker It depends on how `$` is defined (there is no function "$" defined within ECMAScript): `function $ () { /* libraries do what they want */ }`

Comment: @LauriLehtinen that quote made my day

Answer (score 10):

If you are asking why some variables and function names start with `$`, then that is simply a convention when using jQuery and/or AngularJS.

In code that uses **jQuery**, `$` is often used as a prefix for variables that contain jQuery selections.
e.g. `var $container = $('.container');`.

In **AngularJS**, they use the `$` prefix to mean "core Angular functionality". That way, you know which methods and services are added by the framework, and which are custom to your application.