# javascript $ symbol?

Tags: javascript

why $ symbol is used in javascript?
i want to know what it specify?

Comment: In what context? Can you provide some Javascript code snippet involving a `$` in your question? If you're talking about code like `$("#data[select]").val();`, then it's probably jQuery, but that's not necessarily true in all cases.

Comment: Without context (where did you see it used?) this question cannot be reasonably answered. Voting to close as 'not a real question.'

Comment: `$` is a legal character for a variable name in JS. It's often used as a shorthand version of something you call a lot, like the jQuery object. You can use it for wvatever you want. Same happens with the `_` character in PHP (it's an alias for the `gettext()` function).

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3107543/what-is-the-symbol-used-for-in-javascript

Answer (score 16):

You may be looking at jQuery code. $ is a variable (in jQuery's case it's a shortcut for 'jQuery').

Comment: Or anything. AFAIK

Answer (score 6):

You may well be looking at JavaScript written by a PHP programmer!

Answer (score 3):

It's used as a namespace in jQuery.  It's also a pseudonym for the jquery object .