# Why is "$" a valid function identifier?

Tags: javascript, grammar

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Can someone explain the dollar sign in Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/846585/can-someone-explain-the-dollar-sign-in-javascript)
>   [Why would a javascript variable start with a dollar sign?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/205853/why-would-a-javascript-variable-start-with-a-dollar-sign)

Why is it that I can assign a function to `$` in Javascript, but not `#` or `^` ?

Comment: There is other mining of `^` in JS.

Comment: Because the grammar says so. (Not what you wanted to hear? Then be more specific.)

Comment: I would suggest that this is not an *exact* duplicate of the other questions. **edit to add** The other questions are asking why you would *use* the `$` char, this question is asking why `$` is ok vs `#` and `^`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

From the [ECMA standard](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/ECMA-262.pdf) (Section 7.6)

> The dollar sign ($) and the underscore
>   (_) are permitted  anywhere in an
>   *IdentifierName*.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I thought. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Because that is what [ECMA-262](http://www.ecmascript.org/docs.php) specifies (see section 7.6)

Identifiers must match this RegEx: `[a-zA-Z_$][0-9a-zA-Z_$]*`

Answer (score 1):

The reason is because JavaScript is part of the [ECMA-262](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/ECMA-262.pdf) standard.

If you read section 7.6 you'll see the part about *Identifier* syntax.

Essentially the characters that can be used are defined by:

```
Identifier ::
  IdentifierName but not ReservedWord

IdentifierName ::
  IdentifierStart
  IdentifierName IdentifierPart

IdentifierStart ::
  UnicodeLetter
  $
  _
  \
  UnicodeEscapeSequence

IdentifierPart ::
  IdentifierStart
  UnicodeCombiningMark
  UnicodeDigit
  UnicodeConnectorPunctuation
  <ZWNJ>
  <ZWJ>
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question, it's simply because the Javascript interpreter ignores $ as any type of special character.  You can assign a function to a and you can assign one to $.

Much like an underscore, it treats $ as any "normal" character.