# what does $.functionName(); mean in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am not familiar with this syntax.  What does the `$.` mean before the function call?

Comment: Are you using jQuery? In this case it's just a shortcut for the jQuery() function.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can someone explain the dollar sign in Javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/846585/can-someone-explain-the-dollar-sign-in-javascript)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`$` is just a name of some object. It could be jQuery, or Prototype, in case you're using one of these libraries.

So `$.functionName()` simply stands for calling a function named `functionName` of the object named `$`.

Comment: thanks for your comment.  But which object would $ be?  How do I know which object it is?

Comment: @user840930 look at what javascript libraries are used on the page. First of all, look in the page source code and find all `<script scr="...` tags to see which external javascript files are included.

Comment: I see.  Thank you and everyone else for all the replies!

Answer (score 3):

Over here $ sign can be replaced with "jQuery " keyword.

```
$.functionName();
```

is the same as

```
jQuery.functionName();
```

if you are using jQuery framework. If using something else, it may refer to base object as in jQuery.

Answer (score 2):

The dollar sign function has become the more-or-less de facto shortcut to document.getElementById().

http://osric.com/chris/accidental-developer/2008/04/the-javascript-dollar-sign-function/
Check this

And is used by Jquery, Mootools or any other javascript frameworks. Even you can make one

This is a small example

```
function $(obj) {
    return document.getElementById(obj);
}
```

Comment: "De facto" standards should burn in hell. I've had enough fun watching people complain about Chrome breaking "de facto" properties order that "de jure" was always undefined.

Comment: true, but its not the "De facto" problem, it's the browsers w3c implementation on html,javascript,css, the problem.

Comment: But before 3 years, the task of browsers keeping the "De facto standards" was worse. Now days things are much more better.

Answer (score 1):

$ - is just an object name, since $ is valid symbol in JavaScript identifiers. This is not some special syntax, just a regular retrieving of 'functionName' property from object and calling it. Some libraries (like jQuery, for example) alias their main object to this short name to make calls take less space.

Answer (score 0):

This is alias for [JQuery](http://jquery.com/) object or [Prototype](http://www.prototypejs.org/) or [MooTools](http://mootools.net/). Also you can see _. - [Underscore](http://documentcloud.github.com/underscore/).