# Javascript $ notation

Tags: javascript, jquery

Please can anyone explain what this javascript code exactly does.

```
$('#element_id').html(response.title);
```

I need to access the value of the element_id but I can't using document.getElementById.

Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/846585/can-someone-explain-the-dollar-sign-in-javascript

Comment: `"but I can't using document.getElementById"` - Why can't you?  `document.getElementById` should get the element with the given ID.

Comment: what sort of element is this? a span, a text input box, a dropdown (which has a text and a value and a selected index). .val() gets many values, but value doesn't mean the same thing in all contexts.

Comment: [What is the XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: Please ask about your actual problem. It seems you've deviated from your issue onto something tangentially related at best.

Answer (score 2):

This code just calls a function named `$` and access a method of the returned object.

It's probably jQuery code due to the selector string.

- `$('#element_id')`: Returns a jQuery object for the element with the given ID.
- `.html(response.title)`: Sets the inner HTML of the DOM element to `response.title`.

The raw JavaScript would look like this:

```
document.getElementById("element_id").innerHTML = response.title;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot ComFreek. Now I understand the code. I would never have guessed $ as a function name though.

Answer (score 1):

This code uses probably [JQuery](http://jquery.com/). The `$` is the basic function defined by JQuery. You can call it to get access to element using a special query language defined by JQuery.

Answer (score 1):

$ probably refers to jQuery, one of the most frquently used JS libraries.

What this snippet basically does is setting the HTML content of the element with the id *element_id* to the title attribute of the response object.

Comment: $ might refers to anything except jQuery **plugin**.

Comment: jQuery is not a plugin, it's just a library of JS utility functions. Furthermore, `$` can be set to anything. It does not need to be jQuery. (I am not the one who has downvoted).

Comment: you can be SURE it is jQuery, no need t downvote for this. And you are right, jQuery is a library which can be extended using plugins.

Comment: the question has been added an jquery tag, so it IS jquery.

Comment: @luk2302 why can you be sure it is jQuery?

Comment: @luk2302 It wasn't the original OP, it was MatthewMartin (see revision log). But yes, it's probably jQuery ;) +1 from me.

Comment: i know, it wasn´t jQuery from the beginning, but i´d say 99% ;)

Comment: @luk2302, please update yor answer, using the `might be`, `could be` `probably` keywords is more appropriate to refers $ to a specific JS Object.

Comment: @luk2302 Sorry, I'm in `"use strict"` mode ;)

Answer (score 1):

It looks like jQuery, which is a Javascript library. The `$('#element_id')` creates a jQuery object for the element with the id `element_id` in the DOM. Then `.html(response.title)` will put the value of `response.title` as HTML inside the element.