# jQuery works on desktop but doesn't work on tablets

Tags: android, jquery, ipad, asp.net-mvc-4, tablet

I have a series of jQuery functions that load Partial Views from a MVC4 Controller. This (loading partial views) works very well in normal desktop browsers, but when I publish and view it on a tablet it doesn't work. I should note that other jQuery methods do work on tablets, so it does not appear to be an issue with the .js files not getting included.

Method in question:

```
$("#urls").on("click", function () {
    alert("test");
    $("#content-wrapper").load("/URL/Load?userWebID=" + $getActiveUserID());
    $changeTabColour("urls");
});

$getActiveUserID = function () {
    return $("#sidebar ul").find(".active").find("#userID").html();
}
```

When I click the `<div id="urls">`, the "test" alert box appears but the `PartialView` does not load.

Comment: Can you add more details to "does not work"? Does the "alert('test')" popup? What is the behavior?

Comment: check if the URL is correct, also try to debug it using Logcat in case you are using an Android tablet

Comment: Should it be `var $getActiveUserID = function () {` instead?

Comment: Relevant? http://stackoverflow.com/a/846613/2191572

Comment: By "does not work" I mean nothing, other than the alert(), happens when the URLs div is clicked. I state this in the question.

Comment: What happens if you try `alert($getActiveUserID());`?

Comment: @MonkeyZeus alert($getActiveUserID()) shows the UserID correctly.

Comment: Can you convert `.load()` into `.ajax()` and see if the issue persists?

Comment: Found the solution, answered my own question. It was my mistake. Thanks for your help anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am answering my own question for future reference.

This was an ASP.NET problem, caused by the tablet device loading the `Index.Mobile.cshtml` file, rather than the `Index.cshtml` file that the desktop was loading.