# What does the command that start with '$.' do/mean in Javascript? This is NOT '$' selector to select an element

Tags: javascript, jquery, flot

I am looking for the name of the set of commands that start with '$.'. Example: $.extend() in jquery.

Thank you for your help. :)

Comment: It's a method in `$`.

Comment: `$` are a variable just like everything else. But the `$` variable are generally used by some JavaScript libraries, like jQuery.

Comment: Does this help?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/846585/can-someone-explain-the-dollar-sign-in-javascript

Comment: $. is mainly used by the jQuery library.
In fact, $. is an alias to the jQuery object. You can either do $.func() or jQuery.func()

Comment: It is used as an annotation for jquery functions/variable,  which is a javascript framework.

Comment: `$` is jQuery's only function and there are some public utility functions you may use from it, such as `$.trim`, `$.merge`, `$.ajax` or as you say `$.fn` which is the 'namespace' for plugins. Selecting an element with `$('selector')` returns a jQuery Object where you can access your jQuery methods and plugins functions for doing stuff with DOM elements. You would not be adding methods directly on to `$` yourself.

Comment: I use $('elementName') a lot, but it is the public utility functions I am looking to learn about... the '$.' notation, not the jquery selector of '$'.

Comment: I found the jquery tutes for it... https://api.jquery.com/category/utilities/ ... if Dominic wants to post his answer as the answer, i can give you credit. :)

Comment: this q is not a duplicate... '$' is different than '$.' in jquery.

Comment: @Rainhider: No, it’s not. `$` is a function and `$.x` is a property `x` on that function. It’s the same as any other variable name. jQuery isn’t magic.