# Understanding an example async function in js-assessment

Tags: javascript, jquery, asynchronous

I am just beginning to learn javascript, and have been provided the following answer to one of the js-assessment asynchronous testing problems.

```
var dfd = $.Deferred();
setTimeout(function() {
  dfd.resolve(value);
}, 10);
return dfd.promise();
```

I believe the above code is supposed to resolve the function after 10 seconds, but I've had trouble understanding the syntax. I am suspicious that it might be deprecated or an older style.

Does the `$.Deferred()` represent a promise because of the $? According to [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/846585/can-someone-explain-the-dollar-sign-in-javascript) it's just a random variable name (it can be easily be replaced with something like `example_promise` but I suspect might be wrong. Does a promise have to have a `.resolved()` function inside of it? And last, do I have to specify `return dfd.promise()` vs `return dfd`?

It might be much to ask, but basically I'd like a line-by-line breakdown of what's going on and why.

Comment: What you are looking at are jQuery's deferred objects (hence the `$`): http://learn.jquery.com/code-organization/deferreds/jquery-deferreds/ . They are similar to promises, but have a slightly different API.

Comment: Awesome. I didn't even realize I was looking at jQuery, I thought I was learning Javascript.

Comment: And yet you tagged the question with jQuery ;)

Comment: @JosephCho jQuery **is javascript**, it's just a library that makes writing javascript simpler

Comment: If you want to learn about native promises in JS, have a look at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise .

Comment: Thank you all! Clearly I'm just starting to learn.

Comment: @DelightedD0D: *" it's just a library that makes writing javascript simpler"* Lets say it makes working with the DOM and XMLHTTPRequest APIs easier.

Comment: @FelixKling , that's a fair correction :)

Comment: Could someone comment so I can close this question out? I'm not sure how to do it otherwise.

Comment: Just click the checkmark next to your answer, but I think you have to wait 2 days to accept it when you answer your own question, Or you could just delete the question as it's not likely to help anyone in the future. I mean no offense by that, its just not likely to match any search someone does in the future looking for the same type of answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the syntax wasn't outdated or anything, I was just ignoring everything related to jQuery only to realize jQuery is part of javascript. For those just starting to learn, the links in the comments section are useful reading.