# How to understand the $()?

Tags: javascript, jquery

In the following code, what does the empty jQuery selector `$()` mean? Does it mean `$(document)`?

```
 var menu = {
  setting:{
      isSimpleData:true,
      treeNodeKey:"mid",
      treeNodeParentKey:"pid",
      showLine:true,
      root:{
          isRoot:true,
          nodes:[]
      }
  } ,
  loadMenuTree:function(){
      $("#menuTree").zTree(menu.setting, privilegeDate);
  }
};

$().ready(function(){
    menu.loadMenuTree();
});
```

Comment: https://api.jquery.com/ready/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can someone explain the dollar sign in Javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/846585/can-someone-explain-the-dollar-sign-in-javascript)

Comment: "How to understand the `$()`?" [read the api](http://api.jquery.com/jquery/), [and the code](http://code.jquery.com/jquery.js).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> does it mean `$(document)`?

No, it means an empty jQuery collection, but `$.fn.ready` doesn’t actually care what’s in the jQuery collection:

```
> $().length
0

> $.fn.ready
function (a){return n.ready.promise().done(a),this}
```

Note how it doesn’t make use of `this` except to return it for chaining. You could use `$(document).ready`, `$().ready`, `$('body').ready`, `$('blink').ready`… but the only [non-deprecated way](https://api.jquery.com/ready/) is by passing the listener to the jQuery function itself:

```
$(function () {
    menu.loadMenuTree();
});
```

Comment: Whats meaning of `$.fn`?

Comment: @244boy: It’s the jQuery prototype. jQuery collections are instances of the `jQuery` type, and they inherit all their properties from `jQuery.prototype`, for which `$.fn` is shorthand.