# Javascript: What does the $ before the function mean?

Tags: javascript

What does the $ before the function mean in Javascript?  I found this in a Javascript script for a Chromium extension.

```
$(function() {
  $('#search').change(function() {
     $('#bookmarks').empty();
     dumpBookmarks($('#search').val());
  });
});
```

Comment: Most probably https://jquery.com/

Comment: The answer is given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/846585/can-someone-explain-the-dollar-sign-in-javascript)

Comment: `$` is the defined signal of [JQuery](jquery.com): a fast, small, and feature-rich JavaScript library.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks like [jQuery](https://jquery.com/) but could also be any number of web frameworks.

`$` is simply a variable (in this case a function) name, just like any other JavaScript variable name. It likely is also available and aliased as `jQuery`.

You can confirm and see the version using the below in a browser's developer console while on the website.

```
$ === jQuery
> true
```

```
$.fn.jquery
> "1.12.1"
```

Answer (score 1):

It means it is a function of a JQuery object, a popular [javascript library](https://jquery.com/)

Answer (score 0):

This could be an Immediately-invoked Function Expressions with jQuery. `$` is equal to '`jQuery`'. With the immediate function, you can define variables inside the context of the function and avoid global variable definitions. As soon as jQuery loads this function executes.