# What do the dollar-sign ( $ ) do before variables in Cypress (in then clauses)

Tags: jquery, cypress, cypress-intercept

In [the Cypress documentation for Variables and Aliases](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/core-concepts/variables-and-aliases) it uses the dollar sign before the variables in the `then`-clauses. Like this:

```js
cy.get('button').then(($btn) => {
  // $btn is the object that the previous
  // command yielded us
})
```

But I can't figure out why.

There are [many](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/205853/why-would-a-javascript-variable-start-with-a-dollar-sign) [other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/846585/what-is-the-purpose-of-the-dollar-sign-in-javascript) posts simply saying a bunch of stuff about "that it's just another character" so nothing special. And also a bunch of mentions of jQuery, obviously.

I just had an example of a complex Cypress-command, that didn't work, because I *didn't* have the dollar sign. Here is my code:

**The Command**

```js
Cypress.Commands.add( "verifyUsersAccessToArticle", ( articleFixture, userType ) => {
  cy.fixture( articleFixture, "utf8" ).as( 'article' );

  // Intercept async-loaded content XHR
  cy.get( "@article" ).then( ($article) => {
    cy.intercept({
      method: 'GET',
      url: '/wp-json/sn/public/v1/article/' + $article.postId,
    }).as('postContentFull');
  });

  // Log in
  cy.visit( Cypress.env( 'baseUrl' ) );
  if( userType !== 'noUser' ){
    cy.loginUser( userType );
  }

  // Go to article
  cy.get( "@article" ).then( ($article) => {
    cy.visit( Cypress.env( 'baseUrl' ) + $article.url );
  });

  // Let content load
  cy.wait( 1000 );
  if( userType !== 'noUser' ){
    cy.userIsLoggedIn();
  }

  cy.get( "@article" ).then( ($article) => {

    // Have access
    if( $article[ userType ].hasAccess ){
      cy.get( '@postContentFull' ).then( ( $postContentFull ) => {
        expect( $postContentFull.response.statusCode ).to.equal( 200 );
        cy.get( '#main .post-content' ).children().its( 'length' ).should( 'be.gte', 4 ); // 4 <p>'s
        cy.get('.react-pay-product-paywall').should( 'not.exist' );
      });
    }

    // Doesn't have access
    if( ! $article[ userType ].hasAccess ){
      cy.get( '@postContentFull' ).then( ( $postContentFull ) => {
        expect( $postContentFull.response.statusCode ).to.equal( 402 );
        cy.get( '#main .post-content' ).children().its( 'length' ).should( 'be.lte', 4 ); // 4 <p>'s
        cy.get('.react-pay-title').contains( $article[ userType ].paywallTitle );
        cy.get('.react-pay-card-price > span').contains( $article[ userType ].paywallPrice );
      });
    }
  });
});
```

**The Test**

```js
it( 'Verify users access to article', () => {
  
  let articles = [
  'foo-article',
  'bar-article'
  ];

  articles.forEach( (article) => {
    cy.verifyUsersAccessToArticle( Cypress.env( 'name' ) + '/' + article, 'subscriptionTypeZero' );
  });

});
```

If I wrote `postContentFull` instead of `$postContentFull`, then I'm getting an error on the second run (when it runs the iteration for the `bar-article`):

```
- then      function(){} 
TypeError 

Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'statusCode')
```

[image: Cannot read properties of undefined]

**Overarching question**

What does that dollar sign do?
And am I blind - or why can I not find it in the Cypress documentation?

---

### Update 1: I might have misunderstood something

I think I have a flakey test - and have incorrectly assumed that the dollar sign was the solution. But I'm pretty sure that it's simply because the `@article` (that is intercepted) hasn't resolved, when the `cy.get( "@article" ).then( ($article) => {` is executed.

And when I added the dollar sign, the server simply returned faster.

I still would like to figure out, what the dollar sign does. :-)

Comment: The two duplicate post you link to already have the answer: it means nothing special, it's just part of the variable name of a callback's parameter. You can drop it entirely, as long as you rename everywhere, and it'll work the same. Sort of a convention prefix, but nothing else.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the purpose of the dollar sign in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/846585/what-is-the-purpose-of-the-dollar-sign-in-javascript)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ditto comments above, but further info -

You should `wait` on the intercept, not `get` it.

`cy.get('@postContentFull')` will ***only*** work if the intercept has already intercepted.

Also, since you construct a new intercept for each article make the alias unique (otherwise you can't be sure which intercept you get).

```js
cy.fixture( articleFixture, "utf8" )
  .then(article => {                // convention: no $ here, since it's not jQuery

    const alias = 'postContentFull' + article.postId
    cy.intercept('/wp-json/sn/public/v1/article/' + article.postId)
      .as(alias)

    cy.visit('/');                 // visit baseUrl
    if(userType !== 'noUser') {
      cy.loginUser(userType);
    }

    cy.visit(article.url);         // Cypress prepends baseUrl

    cy.wait('@' + alias).then(() => {

      if(article[userType].hasAccess) {
        ...
      } else {
        ...
      }

    })
  })
```