# jQuery Intellisense using something other than $

Tags: javascript, jquery, intellisense

I'm currently using two libraries (prototype and jQuery), thus I've implemented the jQuery noConflict method and set it equal to $j:

var $j = jQuery.noConflict();

Problem is, now the jquery-1.3.2-vsdoc.js doesn't recognize my $j as a valid entry argument.

Is there a way to change this? I've played around with the jquery-1.3.2-vsdoc.js and had no results.

Thanks!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On line 51 of jquery-1.3.2-vsdoc.js, replace

```
jQuery = window.jQuery = window.$ = function(selector, context) {
```

with

```
jQuery = window.jQuery = window.$ = window.$j = function(selector, context) {
```

you'll be lying a little bit to Studio, since the source of the -vsdoc no longer matches the executing source, but it should be a safe hack.

Comment: Ahh, I was so close! I tried adding simply $j into that query! Thanks, you rock!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using an identifier that doesn't start with a dollar sign? I know that's [the convention](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/205853/why-would-a-javascript-variable-start-with-a-dollar-sign/553734#553734), but it might be mucking with your intellisense. Just a thought. Good luck!

Comment: Good question, but it didn't work :(. Whatever I do I believe I'm going to have to modify the vsdoc file to include it...I just can't figure it out :(.