# x = y =1 in Scala?

Tags: scala, return-value, variable-assignment, return-type

While going through the book [Scala for the Impatient](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321774094), I came across this question:

> Come up with one situation where the assignment x = y = 1 is valid in
>   Scala. (Hint: Pick a suitable type for x.)

I am not sure what exactly the author means by this question. The assignment doesn't return a value, so something like `var x = y = 1` should return Unit() as the value of x. Can somebody point out what might I be missing here?

Thanks

Comment: I strongly suspect that the author was *not* thinking of x as of Unit type - that by "valid", they meant to imply "and have some purpose".

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In fact, `x` is `Unit` in this case:

```
var y = 2
var x = y = 1
```

can be read as:

```
var y = 2
var x = (y = 1)
```

and finally:

```
var x: Unit = ()
```

Comment: So the whole point of this question is to show that var x = y = 1 is valid?

Answer (score 6):

You can get to the point of being able to type `x=y=1` in the REPL shell with no error thus:

```
var x:Unit = {}
var y = 0
x = y = 1
```

Comment: That's what I had in mind, except that I would have written `var x = ()`

Answer (score 3):

Here’s another less known case where the setter method returns its argument. Note that the type of `x` is actually `Int` here:

```
object AssignY {
  private var _y: Int = _
  def y = _y
  def y_=(i: Int) = { _y = i; i }
}

import AssignY._

var x = y = 1
```

*(This feature is used in the XScalaWT library, and was discussed in [that question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4967492/about-scalas-assignments-and-setter-methods).)*

Comment: Clearly, this is not what I had in mind :-) But if you want weird solutions, how about `implicit def unit2int(u: Unit) = 42; var x = 1; var y = 2; x = y = 1`

Answer (score 1):

BTW if assigning of the same value to both variables still required then use:

```
scala> var x@y = 1
x: Int = 1
y: Int = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

It's valid, but not sensible, this make confusion.

```
scala> var x=y=1
x: Unit = ()

scala> y
res60: Int = 1

scala> var x@y = 1
x: Int = 1
y: Int = 1
```