# What does an exclamation mark mean after the name of a function?

Tags: julia

I saw a function like this

```
function operator!(c::Matrix, out::Matrix)
    ......
end
```

What does `!` mean here?

Answer (score 68, accepted):

In Julia, it's a convention to [append `!` to names of functions that modify their arguments](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/style-guide/#bang-convention). The reason is Julia function arguments are [passed-by-sharing](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/functions/#Argument-Passing-Behavior), without this "bang" convention, it's not easy to know whether a function will change the content of input arguments or not.

Comment: I'm reading this code, then why the programmer has added another copy of the function, without `!` after the definition of the function? Like `operator(V::Matrix; policy=false) =
    operator!(V, similar(V); policy=policy)`

Comment: @ReD How does `operator!` being implemented?

Comment: > why the programmer has added another copy of the function, without ! after the definition of the function?

Because the function without the ! is not mutable - that is, it doesn't change any of its inputs. Notice that it creates a separate matrix (via similar(V)) which does get mutated in operator!(), but it does not return it. If you call operator(), none of your inputs will change. If you call operator!(), at least one of your inputs (namely, the second one) will be mutated.

Comment: And what it means in expression such as AAA[!,1] ?

Comment: @skan, it's specific to dataframes and says that you want a reference to the underlying vector storing the data, rather than a copy of it (see [SO Ans](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60900196), [docs](https://dataframes.juliadata.org/stable/lib/indexing/#getindex-and-view-1))