# What is the meaning of the exclamation mark in indexing a Julia DataFrame?

Tags: julia

I thought that the exclamation mark `!` is the symbol for the logical `NOT` operator. Now, learning indexing in the `DataFrames` package, I came across this: `data[!,:Treatment]`. Which seems to be the same as using the known colon symbol `:`

`data[:,:Treatment]==data[!,:Treatment]` is `true`.

Why this redundancy then?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`!` in indexing is specific to `DataFrames`, and signals that you want a reference to the underlying vector storing the data, rather than a copy of it. You can read all about indexing `DataFrames` [here](https://juliadata.github.io/DataFrames.jl/stable/lib/indexing/#getindex-and-view-1). In your example the are both `==` because all values are identical, but they are not `===` since `df[:, :Treatment]` gives you a copy of the underlying data.

Example:

```
julia> using DataFrames

julia> df = DataFrame(y = [1, 2, 3]);

julia> df[:, :y] == df[!, :y] # true because all values are equal
true

julia> df[:, :y] === df[!, :y] # false because they are not the same vector
false
```

Comment: So is this the same as the dereference operator `*` in C-like languages?

Comment: You can think of a dataframe as (more or less) a `struct` containing vectors -- one per column. `df[!, :y]` is the same vector as `df.y`, meaning that both vectors point to the same chunk of memory.

Comment: a small comment is that `df[!, :y]` is allowed as LHS of broadcasting assignment while `df.y` is not allowed if `:y` is not present in `df` (due to restrictions of Base). Also `df[!, cols]` can be used to create a new data frame containing multiple columns from `df` without copying them (as opposed to `df[:, cols]` which will freshly allocate all columns).

Answer (score 11):

Quoting the documentation of [DataFrames.jl](http://juliadata.github.io/DataFrames.jl/latest/man/getting_started/#The-DataFrame-Type-1):

> Columns can be directly (i.e. without copying) accessed via `df.col` or `df[!, :col]`. [...] Since `df[!, :col]` does not make a copy, changing the elements of the column vector returned by this syntax will affect the values stored in the original `df`. To get a copy of the column use `df[:, :col]`: changing the vector returned by this syntax does not change `df`.

An example might make this clearer:

```
julia> using DataFrames

julia> df = DataFrame(x = rand(5), y=rand(5))
5×2 DataFrame
│ Row │ x        │ y         │
│     │ Float64  │ Float64   │
├─────┼──────────┼───────────┤
│ 1   │ 0.937892 │ 0.42232   │
│ 2   │ 0.54413  │ 0.932265  │
│ 3   │ 0.961372 │ 0.680818  │
│ 4   │ 0.958788 │ 0.923667  │
│ 5   │ 0.942518 │ 0.0428454 │
```

```
julia> # `a` is a copy of `df.x`: modifying it will not affect `df`

julia> a = df[:, :x]
5-element Array{Float64,1}:
 0.9378915597741728
 0.544130347207969
 0.9613717853719412
 0.958788066884128
 0.9425183324742632

julia> a[2] = 1;

julia> df
5×2 DataFrame
│ Row │ x        │ y         │
│     │ Float64  │ Float64   │
├─────┼──────────┼───────────┤
│ 1   │ 0.937892 │ 0.42232   │
│ 2   │ 0.54413  │ 0.932265  │
│ 3   │ 0.961372 │ 0.680818  │
│ 4   │ 0.958788 │ 0.923667  │
│ 5   │ 0.942518 │ 0.0428454 │
```

```
julia> # `b` is a view of `df.x`: any change made to it will be reflected in df

julia> b = df[!, :x]
5-element Array{Float64,1}:
 0.9378915597741728
 0.544130347207969
 0.9613717853719412
 0.958788066884128
 0.9425183324742632

julia> b[2] = 1;

julia> df
5×2 DataFrame
│ Row │ x        │ y         │
│     │ Float64  │ Float64   │
├─────┼──────────┼───────────┤
│ 1   │ 0.937892 │ 0.42232   │
│ 2   │ 1.0      │ 0.932265  │
│ 3   │ 0.961372 │ 0.680818  │
│ 4   │ 0.958788 │ 0.923667  │
│ 5   │ 0.942518 │ 0.0428454 │
```

Note that, since the indexing with `!` does not involve any data copy, it will generally be more efficient.