# Add mean to boxplot in Julia

Tags: julia, mean, boxplot

In R you can add the `mean` to a boxplot like this:

```r
set.seed(7)
values <- runif(100, 0, 1)
boxplot(values)
points(mean(values), col = 'red')
```

[image]

I would like to do the same in Julia with `StatsPlots`. Here is the code:

```
using StatsPlots
boxplot(repeat(['A'],outer=100),randn(300))
```

Output:

[image]

I am not sure how to add a single point (mean) to the boxplot. Is there a similar function like `points`? So I was wondering if anyone knows how to add the mean to a boxplot in Julia like above?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adding context to the tip to use `scatter!`. The difference between `scatter` and `scatter!` already has a good explanation [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45396685/what-does-an-exclamation-mark-mean-after-the-name-of-a-function).

```
julia> using StatsPlots
julia> using Statistics
julia> using Random

julia> Random.seed!(42)
TaskLocalRNG()

julia> val = randn(300);

julia> boxplot(repeat(['A'], outer=100), val, label = "boxplot")

julia> scatter!(['A'], [mean(val)], label = "mean")
```

[image: boxplot combined with scatter point]

Answer (score 1):

If you want a "point" at the mean, you can use a `scatter!` with the means on top of the boxplots.