# What's the difference between ‘var $x’ and ‘var x’ in javascript?

Tags: javascript, variables

What's the difference between `var $x` and `var x` in javascript?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/205853/why-would-a-javascript-variable-start-with-a-dollar-sign

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Nothing. People tend to use the $x syntax because it's easier to remember you're dealing with a jquery object rather than an element or an id.

In general I tend to use something similar to:

```
var $x = $(selector) //$x holds reference to a jquery object
var elX = document.getElementById(id); // elX hold ref to an element node
var xId = $(selector).attr('id'); //xId holds ref to an id attribute
```

Comment: "xId holds ref to an id attribute" - Not really, it just holds a string...

Answer (score 6):

The difference? One variable starts with `$`.

And neither has anything to do with jQuery - it's just javascript.

Answer (score 3):

One declares a variable called `$x`, one declares a variable called `x`. Dollar is a perfectly valid character for a variable name in JavaScript (this isn't really specifically jQuery related as far as I can see).

See ["Why would a javascript variable start with a dollar sign?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/205853/why-would-a-javascript-variable-start-with-a-dollar-sign) for more.

Comment: You can even do i$love$$s as your variable name.  But the real question is what are the differences between the $, $$ and $x native variables?

Answer (score 1):

There is no difference between two in JavaScript. $ is allowed in variable declaration in JavaScript

Answer (score 1):

The dollar prefix is often used in Javascript for global variables. It's merely a convention - Like underscore is often used to denote a private member.