# What is the dollar sign in Javascript, if not jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I did some javascript / jQuery programming a few years ago, and I just started up again. Back then the dollar sign was used for all the jQuery functionality, and if no jQuery library was imported, the dollar sign was not defined.

Today, I started up Firefox, in a completely empty html file with no javascript libraries, and yet the dollar sign points to something. If I open the Firefox console and type **'$'** I get `"function()"`.

1) Is it correct that dollar sign was not assigned, a few years back, or do I remember wrong?

2) What is the **dollar sign**, if not jQuery?

Answer (score 148, accepted):

> 1) Is it correct that dollar sign was not assigned, a few years back, or do I remember wrong?

That's correct and still true.

> 2) What is the dollar sign, if not jQuery?

[Firefox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Web_Console/The_command_line_interpreter#Helper_commands) and [Chrome](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/commandline-api#selector) implement `$`, `$$` and several others as helper commands. Both will set `$$` to `document.querySelectorAll()`, and set `$` to `document.querySelector` if `window.$` hasn't been defined.

So what you're seeing isn't actually standard JavaScript, but a helper in the developer console of your browser. It's also not jQuery (as long as you're not on a page using jQuery). However, it's behaviour is close to the one of `jQuery`, concerning that `querySelector` (for single matches) and `querySelectorAll` (for multiple matches) give you almost the same strength as the jQuery selector.

Comment: OK that is really annoying. It just makes it confusing because it looks like jquery is there but you can't find it anywhere. I guess once you are aware that's going on it could be handy but its really just confusing and could mask bugs.

Comment: Not sure when it was adopted by other browsers, but I see it available also on IE11 and Edge.

Comment: so how do people know if it's jquery? say, you have imported a large library that might have incorporated a few other libs, you wanna know if the jquery is there. please help.

Comment: @Martian2049 I think real jQuery would respond to `$.fn.jquery`

Comment: As of ES 2015, dollar is used in template literals: **Template literals can contain placeholders. These are indicated by the dollar sign and curly braces `(${expression})`** (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)

Comment: @Gaspacchio That should be another answer. However, keep in mind that `$` was not used in a template literal **in this question**.

Comment: Currently, Chrome at least seems to treat `$()` as `document.querySelectorAll()`, exactly the same as `$$()`. This is closer to how jQuery's `$()` function works.

Answer (score 10):

It means nothing to the interpreter just like the underscore

From the ECMAScript specification:

> The dollar sign ($) and the underscore (_) are permitted anywhere in
>   an identifier. The dollar sign is intended for use only in
>   mechanically generated code.

You may also check [JavaScript Dollar Sign ($) - What is it for?](https://web.archive.org/web/20140318023849/http://www.authenticsociety.com/blog/JavaScript_DollarSign)

> By convention, the dollar sign ($), the underscore (_) and even some
>   ASCII character are permitted to be used anywhere in a JavaScript
>   identifier (Source: Ecma Script documentation (7.6 Identifiers,
>   ECMA-262, 3rd Ed.) **the dollar sign is intended for use only in
>   mechanically generated code.** This means that we do not want to use the
>   dollar sign ($) in our indentifier names, unless we are writing a
>   framework. The following is a list of permitted characters that can be
>   used anywhere in an identifier name:

```
IdentifierName ::
IdentifierStart
IdentifierName IdentifierPart
IdentifierStart ::
UnicodeLetter
$
_
UnicodeEscapeSequence
IdentifierPart ::
IdentifierStart
UnicodeCombiningMark
UnicodeDigit
UnicodeConnectorPunctuation
UnicodeEscapeSequence
```

**EDIT:-**

Actually dollar sign function has become the more-or-less de facto shortcut to `document.getElementById()`.

To confirm my point check **[this](https://web.archive.org/web/20140330134536/http://getfirebug.com/wiki/index.php/Command_Line_API#.24.28selector.29)**:

> **$(selector)**
>
> Returns a single element matching the given CSS selector. **In old
>   Firebug versions**, this used to be equivalent to
>   **document.getElementById**.

Comment: That blog link is dead now.

Comment: First part of answer is irrelevant, second part is obsolete and wrong in the context of modern browsers.

Answer (score 7):

`Dollar sign($)` was not assigned, but some browser add function for special usage.

Like Google Chrome, if you type `$` on the console, it will return :

```
function $(selector, [startNode]) { [Command Line API] }
```

This function assigned for Google Chrome Developer Tool, and let debug more easier.

if you type `$('div')`, it will return something like this:

```
e.fn.e.init[178]
```

and include every `div` DOM object in it.

BTW, after you click the right button on the mouse to select element, you can acceess angular.js scope by type `$scope` on the console

Answer (score 4):

Note that `$$` isn’t quite `document.querySelectorAll`, because unlike that function it doesn’t return a `NodeList`:

```js
document.querySelectorAll("p") instanceof NodeList // true

$$("p") instanceof NodeList // false

Array.isArray($$("p")) // true
```

So `$$(selector)` is really more like `Array.from(document.querySelectorAll(selector))`. This means that array methods like `map` and friends, not just `forEach`, are available when using `$$` which is actually quite useful.

Comment: P.S  ```Array.isArray(document.querySelectorAll("p"))``` is false

Answer (score 2):

Just to complete the other answers here, MooTools also uses `$` as a alias to `document.getElementById`.

It does check if the `$` is taken and will then default to `document.id`.

Answer (score 1):

It may be anything, as `$` is a valid variable name, just like `dollar`.

From [ECMAScript](http://es5.github.io/#x7.6) :

```
Identifier ::
IdentifierName but not ReservedWord

IdentifierName ::
IdentifierStart
IdentifierName IdentifierPart

IdentifierStart ::
UnicodeLetter
$
_ 
\ UnicodeEscapeSequence
```

The simplest solution to see what it is and where it is defined would probably to type `$()` and to [put a breakpoint](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/javascript-debugging) on this line.