# Press form submit button if upload format is valid

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I need to press the button "submit" if the upload file format is valid. I have managed to check the format using the JavaScript below. My aim is between // and // ...

```
<script>
function Checkfiles(f){
    f = f.elements;
    if(/.*\.(gif)|(jpeg)|(jpg)|(doc)$/.test(f['filename'].value.toLowerCase()))
        return true; + // and press the button submit //
    alert('Please Upload Gif or Jpg Images, or Doc Files Only.');
    f['filename'].focus();
    return false;
};
</script>
```

And here's the HTML form:

```
<form action="something.php" method="post" name="myForm" onsubmit="return Checkfiles(this);">  
<input type="file" name="filename" accept="/image*/">
<input type="submit" name="submit"> 
</form>
```

Thanks.

Comment: Given that your function is called from the form's `onsubmit`, what effect do you think programmatically pressing the submit button will have? Please describe what you are trying to achieve from the user's point of view.

Comment: Returning `true` submits the form, why would you need to trigger a click on the submit button inside that function ?

Comment: Java is not Javascript.

Answer (score 0):

Do something like:

```
document.querySelector('form[name="myForm"] input[type="submit"]').click();
```

Comment: Why dont you trigger the form's submit event instead?

Comment: You'r right! But I'm just giving an answer to the question,`I need to press the button "submit"`, and the submit event is being called already, so don't know why he needs to trigger a click anyway.

Comment: What do you mean by "In this case the $ isn't jQuery, but the DOMElement"?

Comment: @nnnnnn The `$` is kind of a shortcut to `document.querySelector`. [Read this.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22244912/4267501)

Comment: That shortcut is defined by certain browsers _in the console only_ - it is not available to code running in the current page. (And in the case of the OP's code presumably `$ === jQuery` given that they tagged the question with "jquery".)

Comment: By using the `document.querySelector` you obtain the same expected result