# jquery parse html table should be an array but not

Tags: jquery, html

In this url: http://es.finance.yahoo.com/q/cp?s=%5EJKSE
If I test this selector expresion in the console...

```
 $('#yfncsumtab .yfnc_tableout1 tr td table tbody')
```

...it returns html table (but not in an array):

```
 <table>...</table>
```

Can anybody explain me why I am not obtaining an array contaning the html table??? That's the reason why I cannot apply .each(), .text() ... I think.

When I test the same selector to another website's table it always returns:

```
 [<table>...</table>]
```

And with that response, I can apply .each() o whatever jQuery method.

Comment: I don't think JQuery is included in the webpage.

Comment: First statement doesn't make sense. Please create a demo that diesplays this behavior

Answer (score 0):

Type `jQuery` in the console and you'll see it's undefined.

So what's that `$` then?

[What is the dollar sign in Javascript, if not jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22244823/what-is-the-dollar-sign-in-javascript-if-not-jquery)

Comment: Thank you so much, I didn't know that without jquery implemented in the website I could'nt use it to parse the html. I will try with javascript directly, that's the problem for sure.

Answer (score 0):

Since there is **no JQUERY** in the web page, you can use the following to loop through:

```
document.getElementsByClassName("yfnc_tableout1")[0].getElementsByTagName("table")[0].getElementsByTagName("tr")
```