# attr() showing undefined using jQuery

Tags: jquery, dom, selector, attr

The DOM is something like this:

```
<h3 class="iw"><span email="noreply@updates.com" name="test.com" class="gD">test.com</span></h3>
```

Now I want to get the email attribute of the span.

I tried following in console log.

```
console.log($(".iw span:first-child"));
```

I get the complete inner span element and its other line as undefined on the console.

Now if I try following on console log,

```
console.log($(".iw span:first-child").attr("email"));
```

It starts giving me this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: $(...).attr is not a function(…)
```

It gives the same error for any jQuery method that I may use after that.

Image - 
[image: Error coneol log]

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: do you have more than one `.iw` in your html?

Comment: Its a generic page which I am trying to traverse of gmail single email detail page, it does not seem to have any other on first glance

Comment: It should work then. https://jsfiddle.net/pvk1gcra/

Comment: It works fine : https://jsfiddle.net/wgazmvf0/

Comment: try with `$(".iw span:first").attr("email")`

Comment: Try `.eq(0)`. or `:eq(0)`

Comment: That is the issue I am facing I also have multiple fiddles working with same, but it is not working based on  steps above. Please try to give any inpus based on steps provided above

Comment: @KaushikRay Are those commands somewhere in your code or are you writing that on the browser console? If so, what does it say when you just input `$` and hit enter? If you see `function $(selector, [startNode]) { [Command Line API] }` that's not jQuery

Comment: Thanks Jselser  I will try it out..thanks

Comment: Sounds like something is overwriting jQuery, Make sure you don't use any other JS library.

Comment: Thanks shadow.will be checking in few hours and add update

Comment: @JSelser, You have mentioned correctly, I am writing this on console log and on just running $ I am getting function $(selector, [startNode]) { [Command Line API] }, So does that mean my jquery is not loaded on page? then how come I am able to get normal console.log($(".iw span:first-child")) value on same console?

Comment: @ShadowWizard, Just jquery and bootstrap nothing else

Comment: So try to debug. Start with `console.log($);` - what do you see? (you should get *function (a,b){return new e.fn.init(a,b,h)}*.)

Comment: It gives same as my previous comment - function $(selector, [startNode]) { [Command Line API] }

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22244823/what-is-the-dollar-sign-in-javascript-if-not-jquery contains the answer. Anyway, you do **not** have jQuery, and that's 100% sure. Include jQuery properly, and you will be able to use its methods like `.attr()` and others.

Comment: Ok I will check the link, also added an image with console log commands. If it helps

Comment: You can also post here the HTML code you're using to include jQuery, maybe someone can spot what's wrong with it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The browser console comes with a function `$` that acts like jQuery but isn't. Said function **is only available while on the browser console and not usable in scripts included in your page**

Like aphextwix said in his answer, you should be fine if you include jQuery in your page like:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

If you are absolutely sure you are including jQuery but **still** can't debug in the console with the `$()` try using `jQuery()` like so:

```
console.log(jQuery(".iw span:first-child").attr("email"));
```

Answer (score 0):

This works completely fine, you just need to make sure you're including the jQuery library before trying to `console.log` the `email` attribute.

Place this in the `<head>` of your HTML :

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

So then calling `console.log($(".iw span:first-child").attr("email"));` will return 'noreply@updates.com'.