# jQuery, how to get reference from onclick inline?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

There is something like this:

```
<tr onclick="console.log($(this));">
```

I know its bad but its a legacy code. I would like to get the reference of this TR but this:

```
<tr onclick="console.log($(this));">
```

Nor this:

```
<tr onclick="console.log(this);">
```

Works, it thinks that **this** is `<tr onclick="` event itself.

Comment: `this` refers to the DOM object of the element

Comment: _"nor this:`<tr onclick="console.log(this);">` works, it thinks that this is `<tr onclick="` event itself."_ What is "it"? Can you create a stacksnippets to demonstrate?

Comment: A simple way to not even have this problem is to stop using inline event handlers right now and for good. There is not a single scenario where an inline event handler preferable.

Comment: Being legacy code doesn't mean you can't update it, surely? Unobtrusive JavaScript is rather better from a maintenance point of view, if nothing else.

Comment: @Tomalak _"There is not a single scenario where an inline event handler preferable."_ `Node.cloneNode()`?

Comment: @guest271314 Not a good example. That's what event delegation is for. Also, jQuery has implemented a way to clone nodes with event handlers, see https://api.jquery.com/clone/.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what you expect from `$(this)` to return but it refer to the `tr` as you could see in the example below.

**NOTE :** The `$(this)` keyword refer jQuery object and `this` refer to the DOM object they aren't the same.

Take a look to **[What is the dollar sign in Javascript, if not jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22244823/what-is-the-dollar-sign-in-javascript-if-not-jquery)**.
Hope this helps.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr onclick="console.log($(this).html(),this.innerHTML);">
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
  </tr>
  
  <tr onclick="console.log($(this).html(),this.innerHTML);">
    <td>4</td>
    <td>5</td>
    <td>6</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: console.log($(this).html()); returns "TypeError: $(...).html is not a function". Like I said console.log($(this)); and console.log(this); returns the same

Comment: The `$(this)` object refer jQuery object and `this` refer to the DOM object they aren't the same.

Comment: @ZakariaAcharki Note, `$` can also reference `function $(selector, [startNode]) { [Command Line API] }`

Comment: Yes it may, thanks for your intervention, updated my answer.

Answer (score 1):

It's important to distinguish between jQuery and plain javascript here.

- `$(this)` is a jQuery object and takes jQuery methods.
- `this` is a plain javascript keyword and takes plain javascript methods.

**Example:**

```css
td {
width: 100px;
height: 100px;
line-height: 100px;
font-size: 80px;
text-align: center;
color: rgb(255,255,255);
background-color: rgb(255,0,0);
}
```

```html
<table>
<tr onclick="console.log(this.innerHTML);">
<td>A</td>
<td>B</td>
<td>C</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: That's unfortunate wording. jQuery is native Javascript as well.

Comment: Probably you can help me out here, @Tomalak - I used to refer to library-less javascript as "vanilla javascript". More recently I have referred to it as "native javascript". What is the conventional way to refer to library-less, framework-less javascript?

Comment: "Vanilla" is the term I would use. It's all Javascript, after all. Even the DOM is just an API. In a browser, it's just magically always available. Programming against the DOM is not more less native than programming against a DOM wrapper/utility belt like jQuery. I've seen so many beginners who think that jQuery and Javascript are somehow different things instead of steps on the same pyramid. So I think wording should be such that it does not reinforce that kind of misconception.

Comment: _"`$(this)` is a jQuery object and takes jQuery methods."_ Is jQuery defined? If jQuery is not defined what would `$(this)` reference?

Comment: @guest271314, do you think that '$' function is defined, in this case, and it is not related to jQuery, and it returns current event (?) - errors thrown (html() is not a function) suggest it?

Comment: @sinisake Not certain given total contents of current Question, though a possibility.

Comment: @Tomalak - I've updated _vanilla javascript_ to _plain javascript_. I'm not sure it's much better (though it is marginally) but I've spent thirty-odd minutes searching the web for something better and there seems to be no conventional term for unembellished, unadorned, library-less, framework-less javascript. And the reason I stopped using _vanilla javascript_ is because I began to see how widely the joke is misunderstood.

Comment: Naming is hard, even here. I find "vanilla" easier to explain than "native", if someone does not know the term. That's also why I mentioned the DOM, because it means that in a browser even "vanilla" is not really true. It's not also not true for node.js with no modules loaded, because in node, `fs` is always availabe. It's not easy. :)