# Printing JSON using DOM method to HTML (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, html, json, object, dom

I am trying to use the DOM method to display a JSON object that I created inside of my .js file, and I need to display it in the HTML page.
This is what my code looks like and it is not working.

```
function JSONMethod(){
    carInfo = {"make":"BMW", "model":"M5","mear":"2017","color":"Black"};
    myJSON = JSON.stringify(carInfo);
    localStorage.setItem("theJSON", myJSON);

    text = localStorage.getItem("theJSON");
    obj = JSON.parse(text);

    for(var i = 0; i < obj.length; i++)
    {
        var para = document.createElement("li");
        var node = document.createTextNode(obj[i]);
        para.appendChild(node);
        var element = $("display");
        element.appendChild(para);
    }
}
```

The $ function is this

```
function $(theId){
    return window.document.getElementById(theId);
}
```

Comment: 1) You probably meant `$('#display)` or some other **valid** selector. 2) Objects don't have a `length` property. Try a [`for..in` loop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in). 3) All that local storage stuff is completely superfluous to your question

Comment: I have actually been using just $("display") the entire time, and it seems to be working. I keep seeing around on comments people saying to add the "#". Why so? the $ function just returns the window.document.getElementById(theId)

Comment: My apologies, I assumed you were using jQuery. I wouldn't recommend relying on `$` being defined. Seems like something only Chrome and Firefox do ~ http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22244823/what-is-the-dollar-sign-in-javascript-if-not-jquery

Comment: No worries, I should clarify what the $ function is. Thank you though!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure why exactly you are saving to and then reading from `localStorage`, or stringifying and then reparsing your object. Most of the code you gave above can be removed or reduced in size drastically using constructs like `.textContent` and `Array#forEach`.

Your underlying problem, however, is that you cannot iterate over regular objects using a for-loop and an index. You have to use a function like the built-in `Object.keys` to get all of its properties and then do something with them.

```js
function JSONMethod (carInfo) {

  Object.keys(carInfo).forEach(function (k) {
    var li = document.createElement("li")
    li.textContent = k + ': ' + carInfo[k]
    this.appendChild(li)
  }, document.getElementById('display'))

}

JSONMethod({
  "make": "BMW",
  "model": "M5",
  "mear": "2017",
  "color": "Black"
})
```

```html
<ul id="display"></ul>
```

Comment: Ohhhh ok ok yeah the storing thing I got from the w2schools.com. And the storing isn't necessary now that I realized and found other links. I will try to rearrange my code with your answer and see if it work! Thanks!