# Select inner element with no id by JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom, jquery-selectors

Say I have this `div` block:

```
<div id="some_id" style="display: none;">
    <form action="someAction" method="post">
        <input type="hidden" name="some-name" value="some-value">
    </form>
</div>
```

I need to the select the `form` inside this `div`. I am able to select the `div` by `$('#some_id')` but when I try to select the `form` by `$('#some_id').find('form')` (or `get` or `$('#some_id:form')`) I get this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: $(...).find is not a function
```

Any possible solution?

Comment: `$` is possibly not jQuery?  `console.log($.fn.jquery)` and see if you get a version number.

Comment: I got `Cannot read property 'jquery' of undefined` but how come `$('#some_id')` works?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the dollar sign in Javascript, if not jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22244823/what-is-the-dollar-sign-in-javascript-if-not-jquery)

Comment: The comment is a "Possible duplicate" not the question itself.

Comment: The duplicate may explain why `$` is not jQuery in your use case.  `$('#some_id').find('form')` is a valid operation.  If '$' is not jQuery, the answer to this question is as simple as "include jQuery in your page"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't want a `:` to select the child you want `>`

Your selector should look like this:

```
$('#some_id > form')
```

Also make sure you are including jQuery, it looks like your code cannot find it.

Comment: The `>` is technically unnecessary here.

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing wrong with what you attempted, provided that jQuery is properly included in your page and you are properly referencing it with `$` or `jQuery` if it is in noConflict mode.

```js
console.log(
  $('#some_id').find('form').get()
);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="some_id" style="display: none;">
    <form action="someAction" method="post">
        <input type="hidden" name="some-name" value="some-value">
    </form>
</div>
```