# How to select all the HTML elements having a custom attribute?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I know I can select all the HTML elements with a custom attribute by just doing:

```
$('p[mytag]')
```

As you can see, I also need to specify the actual HTML div type (a `p` element in this case). But what if I need to retrieve all the HTML elements irrespective of their type?

Consider this code:

```
<p>11111111111111</p>
<p mytag="nina">2222222222</p>
<div>33333333333</div>
<div mytag="sara">4444444444</div>
```

how I can select the 2 html elements (the `p` and the `div`) with custom attribute `mytag`?

Comment: $('[mytag]') should do

Comment: @gugateider that actually only selects the first element with the custom tag, not all

Comment: document.querySelectorAll('[mytag]');

Comment: @Danmoreng No, that's incorrect. `$('[mytag]')` will select them all

Comment: Interesting...must be a bad jQuery implementation of webpack/babel on the site I've tested it then...

Comment: @Danmoreng probably you are incorrectly using the subsequent foreach: it sholud be     $("[mytag]").each(function(i, obj){ // do something with obj }

Comment: I got fooled by taking this for jQuery... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22244823/what-is-the-dollar-sign-in-javascript-if-not-jquery

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to use `$("[mytag]")`

```js
console.log($("[mytag]"))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>11111111111111</p>
<p mytag="nina">2222222222</p>
<div>33333333333</div>
<div mytag="sara">4444444444</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [querySelectorAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) (javascript) :

```
document.querySelectorAll('[mytag]');
```

Or even simpler with jQuery:

```
$('[mytag]');
```

Comment: `$('[mytag]');` only selects the first element. `document.querySelectorAll('[mytag]');` works though.

Comment: @Danmoreng No, that's incorrect. `$('[mytag]')` will select them all

Comment: I got fooled by taking this for jquery... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22244823/what-is-the-dollar-sign-in-javascript-if-not-jquery