# Is dollar sign defined in Javascript even without jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ecmascript-6, cross-browser

I know that `$("...")` is of course defined in jQuery ([What is the meaning of "$" sign in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1150381/what-is-the-meaning-of-sign-in-javascript)), and also that some people who don't use jQuery define `$ = document.querySelector` or `$ = document.querySelector.bind(document)`.

In some cases (Firefox, Chrome), `$` seems to be available in the developer console even without loading this library, or without defining `$` manually: see the main answer of [What is the dollar sign in Javascript, if not jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22244823/what-is-the-dollar-sign-in-javascript-if-not-jquery).

**Question: can we assume in 2022 that `$` is an alias in most browsers for `document.querySelector` and can we use it directly in our JS code?**

I know caniuse.com but here neither https://caniuse.com/?search=%24 nor https://caniuse.com/?search=dollar helped.

Example: open a html file containing:

```html
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<div id="a">Hello world</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Open the developer console and do `$('#a')`: it works.

Comment: No, you cannot assume that. The `$` character is a valid character in any identifier; it's no more special than `B`.

Comment: `In some cases (Firefox, Chrome), $ seems to be available in the developer console even without loading this library` I would guess that depends heavily on the currently loaded website; this is in no way some kind of default

Comment: @ChrisG No no, see my edit (example at the end): `$` is directly available in the Chrome dev console even with a website with no library loaded.

Comment: @ChrisG Try this: 1) Save this in `test.html`: `<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<div id="a">Hello world</div>
</body>
</html>`. 2) Open it in Chrome 3) Open dev console 4) Run `$('#a')`: it matches the div.

Comment: @Pointy I know this of course, but try my last comment in the dev console.

Comment: I did. This seems to be a Chrome dev console only thing, so the answer is still "no", you absolutely cannot rely on that. And your <script> isn't executed in the console anyway, so no, browsers do not assign a function to `$` (including Chrome)

Comment: The developer console uses the currently loaded page as part of its context. If you're looking at a page that has loaded jQuery, then `$` will refer to the library. If Chrome or some other browser explicitly makes it available as a reference to *something* then that's their decision (which I personally would consider a bad decision). Note that `.querySelectorAll()` is in very many ways not at all the same thing as the jQuery main entry point.

Comment: @Pointy Yes but of course I was speaking about opening the dev console in the context of a page *without* jquery loaded, such as `test.html`: `<html> <head></head> <body> <div id="a">Hello world</div> </body> </html>`.

Comment: See https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/console/utilities/#querySelector-function: *"`$(selector)` returns the reference to the first DOM element with the specified CSS selector. When called with one argument, this function is an alias for the `document.querySelector()` function. ... Note: If you are using a library such as jQuery that uses `$`, this functionality will be overwritten, and `$` will correspond to that library's implementation."*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No you can't. It's *only* available in developer console in some browsers without importing `jQuery` library.

See https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/console/utilities/#querySelector-function:

> $(selector) returns the reference to the first DOM element with the specified CSS selector. When called with one argument, this function is an alias for the document.querySelector() function.

Here is a simple example:

```js
console.log($('#div'));
```

```html
<div id="div"></div>
```

Comment: In code, yes. But in the **developer console** it works. Try this: 1) Save this in `test.html`: `<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<div id="a">Hello world</div>
</body>
</html>`. 2) Open it in Chrome 3) Open dev console 4) Run `$('#a')`: it matches the div.

Comment: @Basj as I said it is available ONLY in developer console in some browsers. And you asked: `can we use it directly in our JS code?` so answer is no. You can't use it directly in js code without importing `jQuery` library