# How to solve the "Cannot add class to undefined" Error?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a page that I am trying to remove an element of with this section of code

```
oldContainer = $('div.choose-location-options');
oldContainer.addClass('hidden');
```

I am using the `$` selector because I read online and in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22244823/what-is-the-dollar-sign-in-javascript-if-not-jquery) that `$` is short for `document.querySelector`,  this code is working fine.

During code review my colleagues have told me that they do not want us using the `$` is not best practice because it looks like jquery. So I changed it to this.

```
oldContainer = document.querySelector('div.choose-location-options');
oldContainer.addClass('hidden');
```

However this code will return an error message saying that `cannot add class to undefined` 
Running this code in the browser will also remove the `oldContainer` so I thought it was an issue with the page loading so I added an event listener to the code for a page load

```
window.addEventListener('load', (event) => {
   oldContainer = $('div.choose-location-options');
   oldContainer.addClass('hidden');
});
```

This also returns `undefined` So I know it is not a timing issue. Why is the shorthand `$` working but not the `document.querySelector`?

Comment: `$` is not defined by the browser, mostly it **is** jquery, which wraps each element into its own object. what you want is `oldContainer.classList.add('hidden')` in vanilla. also $('selector') will alays return an object. maybe the iterator is empty. the vanilla can return undefined. that why u also need to check for existence.

Comment: `addClass()` is a jQuery method, not a DOM method.

Comment: *I read online and in || that $ is short for document.querySelector* <-- That's incorrect. You are using JQuery and `$(some selector)` is ***similar***, but not exactly the same as `document.querySelectorAll()`.

Comment: "*I am using the $ selector because I read online and in || that $ is short for document.querySelector,*" not really? What is `||`? `$` only has special meaning in the console. If you're using this in your regular code, then there is something that's defining it. And it might be jQuery. "*an error message saying that cannot add class to undefined*" please cite *the exact* message.

Comment: " ...my colleagues have told me that they do not want us using the $ is not best practice because it looks like jquery." This is just nonsense. `$` is just a valid JS identifier.

Comment: jQuery doesn't report an error if a selector doesn't match anything. It's more like `querySelectorAll()` followed by a `forEach()` loop. An empty match just means that the loop is empty.

Comment: Barmar is correct, it turns out the issue was `addClass()` instead of `classList.add` 
And VLAZ the link is now added where || was, apologies for not fixing that before submitting.

Comment: `addClass` in the DOM version should have reported an error that the method doesn't exist, not that you can't add the class.

Comment: And if `oldContainer` is undefined, you'll also get an error from `oldContainer.classList.add()`.