# jQuery $.getScript - old functions & variables in executed script

Tags: jquery, getscript

i execute a javascript with jQuery $.getScript.
In the executed script i haven't access to the functions and variables of my source file.

Is there a solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The script executed by $.getScript() **does** have access to the global context. You can use any global variable (or function for that matter) from within your external script.

Answer (score 1):

Nick Craver, I just spend 3 (!) hours obsessing over why my thing wouldn't work, and you gave me the insight I needed to make it work.

XOXOXOXOXOXOXOXO

interesting to note:

you can declare a variable as a jquery var like this:

```
$variableName = something;
```

That way jquery also has access to it from anywhere in the scope.

```
$(function(){ 
    $alertString = 'Hello World'; 

    $.getScript('test.js', function(){ 
        // do nothing 
    });    
} 

test.js: 

alert( $alertString );
```

Comment: That is quite useful and interesting to know.

Comment: A variable beginning with `$` is nothing special, it works just like any other letter. For reference, see this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/205853/why-would-a-javascript-variable-start-with-a-dollar-sign