# How to read the contents of text area by jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
<textarea id="metaSourceText" name='key' style="width:100%" class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" rows="1"></textarea>
```

I tried

```
$metaSourceValue = $('metaSourceText').val();
alert($metaSourceValue);
```

But it shows "undefined"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your code just needs to be tweaked, to something like this:

```
var metaSourceValue = $('#metaSourceText').val();
alert(metaSourceValue);
```

you were missing the hash before metaSourceText, signaling an ID to jQuery.  And you typically don't want to start variables with $

Comment: As Capsule noted, yes, you can start variables with $, and I think doing so is a good idea for storing jquery selections.

Comment: I think it's just a difference of opinion. I don't think starting string variables should use the $, but that's just my opinion. :)

Comment: The result of a `.val()` is not a jQuery selector object, so no `$` is more appropriate.

Answer (score 2):

You missed the # character in $('#metaSourceText')

Answer (score 0):

.text() method will also give you value of textarea. In ready() state you can either get object of textarea using class selector or id selector.

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
 $("#submitbtn").click(function () {
 var textAreaValue = $("#txtMessage").text();
 alert(textAreaValue);
 });
});
```

Check sample here: http://www.codegateway.com/2012/03/get-textarea-value-in-jquery.html

Answer (score 0):

Please define the selector with '#' prefix as it is an ID you are referring.
In your case, it refers a DOM element of type metaSourceText which really does not exists..

To get a value of this text area:
you can use .text() or val();

```
$(function(){

var textareaContent = $('#metaSourceText').text();
alert(textareaContent);

​}​);​
```

fiddle link:http://jsfiddle.net/Ds4HC/1/

Answer (score -2):

Javascript variables don't start with `$`.  EDIT: They *can*, but usually do not.  See 
[Why would a JavaScript variable start with a dollar sign?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/205853/why-would-a-javascript-variable-start-with-a-dollar-sign))

You want to try:

```
var metaSourceValue = $('#metaSourceText').val();
alert(metaSourceValue);
```

The `$(...)` used by jQuery is a shortcut to the `jQuery` function.

Also, as others mentioned, you need `$('#metaSourceText')` if you're trying to reference the textarea by id - you were missing the `#`.

Comment: Wrong, a variable can actually start with $. It's not necessary but it won't break anything.

Comment: Many people use the $ to indicate that its a jQuery object (or any other framework which uses the dollar sign). In this case it wouldn't be a jQuery object though, as `.val()` returns a string.

Comment: Ah yes, you're right - thanks for the correction.  Related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/205853/why-would-a-javascript-variable-start-with-a-dollar-sign