# jQuery: Why prepend a $ to variable name?

Tags: jquery

I am trying to learn jQuery and I came across this line in an example.

```
var $title = $(tag).attr('title');
```

Can someone please tell me what the prepended $ is for in `$title`.

The example seems to work fine if I replace `$title` with just `title`.

I understand this is probably a stupid question but it is a waste of time googling for "purpose of $"

Many thanks.

Comment: It's just to say that it is a jQuery object and that you don't need to $() it again in order to avoid unnecessary function calls.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why would a JavaScript variable start with a dollar sign?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/205853/why-would-a-javascript-variable-start-with-a-dollar-sign)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It doesn't "mean" anything.  The `$` character is a legal character in Javascript variable names.

However, there is a convention (which isn't universal) of using `$` as a prefix to any variable that points to a jQuery selection.

You give the example:

```
var $title = $(tag).attr('title');
```

This is a bad use of the `$` character, according to this convention.  `$title` is a string, not a jQuery selection.

This would be a correct use of the character:

```
var $el = $(tag);
var title = $el.attr('title');
```

---

Otherwise, a big reason for the prevalence of the `$` character is that it is mandatory in PHP, and there is a big overlap between jQuery and PHP programmers.

Comment: Thank you very much to all those kind enough to respond. I understand perfectly now.

Answer (score 1):

I think people use it as a convention for 'things I looked up with jQuery that I want to hold onto without needing to look up again'.

The one you see most often is `var $this = $(this)`

Answer (score 1):

$ is a valid character in javascript variable names. It makes no difference in the snipped you posted. See [this related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1661197/valid-characters-for-javascript-variable-names/1661249#1661249).

Answer (score 1):

Looks like a PHP developer was getting a bit tired and didn't realise he was in a javaScript code block.

Answer (score 0):

In JavaScript you don't need to have $ on variable names. However, to access the element using jQuery (usually by the $) you'll need the $ on the `('#selector_id')` bit - i.e. `$('#selector_id')`.

The intent of this is to denote to the programmer that the variable is a jQuery wrapper object.

Answer (score -1):

In javascript `$` is nothing. This is the same as add `a` to title (`atitle`). It's just a symbol you can use for names.

Answer (score -2):

there is no purpose for $, it's just named that way. =)

Comment: read above, it explains the non-universal convention for meaning the variable is a jquery selection

Answer (score -3):

The symbol '$' is mapped to the jQuery class.  There is NO reason to prefix title with '$'.