# Declaring variables jQuery and JS

Tags: javascript, jquery

It may be a silly question but I haven't been able to find any documentations on this on the internet.

When declaring variables to use within Javascript i normally use `var x = 0` but I've seen in jQuery tutorials that they use `$x = 0`. What is the difference of those two ?

Also, would i call those two variables the same way or do i need to use the $ mark before ?
So for example : `for(i=0; i < x; i++)` or `for(i=0; i < $x; i++)`

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Your `var x = 0;` is fine. The only reason people sometimes use a `$` with jQuery-specific variables is that it helps them remember that the variable contains the result of a call to the `$()` function in jQuery. The `$` is actually part of the variable name, so you would use `$` everywhere you referred to the variable.

So this:

```
var x = $(".foo");      // Find all elements with class "foo"
x.css("color", "blue"); // Make them all blue
```

Is exactly the same as this:

```
var $x = $(".foo");      // Find all elements with class "foo"
$x.css("color", "blue"); // Make them all blue
```

They've just put a `$` at the beginning of the name.

Note: You've quoted your "jQuery" example as simply `$x = 0;` (without `var`). Be sure you always declare your variables (using `var`); otherwise, you're falling prey to the [Horror of Implicit Globals](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/03/horror-of-implicit-globals.html).

Answer (score 9):

The dollar sign `$` is not a special character in JavaScript. It is a legal character in variable naming. Here's what constitutes a [legal identifier in JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Guide/Values,_Variables,_and_Literals#Variables):

> A JavaScript identifier must start with a letter, underscore (_), or dollar sign ($); subsequent characters can also be digits (0-9). Because JavaScript is case sensitive, letters include the characters "A" through "Z" (uppercase) and the characters "a" through "z" (lowercase).
>
> Starting with JavaScript 1.5, you can use ISO 8859-1 or Unicode letters such as å and ü in identifiers. You can also use the \uXXXX Unicode escape sequences as characters in identifiers.
>
> Some examples of legal names are `Number_hits`, `temp99`, and `_name`.

Some jQuery programmers (myself included) use the `$` as a prefix on variable names to indicate that those variables refer to [jQuery objects](http://api.jquery.com/Types/#jQuery).

#### See also

- [jQuery: Why prepend a $ to variable name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5754087/why-prepend-a-to-variable-name)
- [The $ dollar sign](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1180213/jquery-the-dollarsign)
- [What characters are valid for JavaScript variable names?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1661197/valid-characters-for-javascript-variable-names)

Answer (score 5):

No difference. The `$` is just another character in  JavaScript.

It just happens that jQuery users use it to signify a variable that is referencing a jQuery object. There's no requirement though.