# Add class to parent on click jquery

Tags: jquery

this script should do:

```
  var  link = $("a"),
    rate = $('<div><a href="" class="fa fa-check-circle good"></a><a href="" class="fa fa-times-circle bad"></a></div>'),
    good = $(".good"),
    wrong = $(".bad");
    good.on("click", function() {
        $(this).closest("th").addClass("good");
    });
    wrong.on("click", function() {
        $(this).closest("th").addClass("verybad");
    });
```

- If I click to th show div with two a elements
- If I click to  element, for example with class .good, it should add parent .good class.

you can find whole code [here](http://codepen.io/marciapn/pen/ZbEqOy/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use event delegation (as you are appending dynamically those `.good` and `.bad` DOM element):

```
$(document).on("click", "a", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
});
$(document).on("click", ".good", function() {
    $(this).closest("th").addClass("good");
});
$(document).on("click", ".bad", function() {
    $(this).closest("th").addClass("verybad");
});
```

Also, you have a typo in your CSS, should be:

```
.verybad { /* note the "y" you missed */
    color:  #e07ccd;
}
```

Finally, take the habit of [prepending your variable names by `$`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5754099/2788131) if they store a jQuery object for better readability.

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/k46gw88x/3/)