# Use of $ in regular method

Tags: javascript, jquery

I go over some code and I saw the following code

```
  var failedExtPlugins = PluginR.$getFailPlug();
```

It seems that this time the $ is not refer to jquery object (yes I know that when you use Jquery you start with $) I guess,so what does it mean?
it look like regular method...but way the use $

Comment: This might answer your question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6209462/when-why-to-prefix-variables-with-when-using-jquery

Comment: @sriniprash- I know that you can define varibale but I dont think that this is the case...

Comment: In JS the `$` is an ordinary character in variable names, just like the `_`. Anyone can use it for any purpose. It has no exclusive connection to jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

It looks just like a part of a name. I like to use $ in a name of jQuery objects I have. Maybe author has some thoughts about that.

Answer (score 0):

Its a jQuery wrapped object. $ObjectName reflects that its holding a reference of jQuery wrapped object of particular dom object.
For Example:

```js
var $obj = $("#SomeId");
```