# Writing a counter to count the number of clicks

Tags: javascript, jquery, counter

I have two buttons on my website. Next and previous. I want to write a code to increase the value each time next is clicked and decrease the value each time previous is clicked. I want the value to be shown in an input. But the value shown in input is always 0 and does not change with clicks.

Here is my code:

```
function count(){
    var $counter=0;
    $(".next-button").click(function() {
         $counter=$counter+1;
    });
    $(".previous").click(function() {
        $counter=$counter-1;
    });
    return $counter;
}

document.getElementById('counter').value =count();
```

Comment: It's because the `count()` always reset `$counter` to 0 . Plus, Javascript is not PHP. no `$` sign is needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do like this:

```
var $counter = 0;

$(".next-button").click(function() {
    $counter = $counter + 1;
    refreshCount();
});
$(".previous").click(function() {
    $counter = $counter - 1;
    refreshCount();
});

function refreshCount() {
    document.getElementById('counter').value = $counter;
}

//init
refreshCount();
```

Comment: not suggested to mix traditional Javascript DOM with jQuery objects, but the codes are still valid.

Comment: @Raptor Yes. use this:

`$('#counter').val( $counter );`

 better ~

Answer (score 2):

You don't need `return` in this function. In fact, you don't need a function at all. Instead, show the `counter` whenever you update it.

```
var $counter=0;
$(".next-button").click(function() {
     $('#counter').val($counter++);
});
$(".previous").click(function() {
    $('#counter').val($counter--);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you should update value in element each time it changes:

```
(function count(){
    var counter=0,
        $container = $('#counter');
    $(".next-button").click(function() {
        $container.text(++counter);
    });
    $(".previous").click(function() {
        $container.text(--counter);
    });
})();
```

Answer (score 0):

Declare counter globally so it will initialized only once

```js
var $counter=0;
  var count=document.getElementById('counter');
     $(".next").click(function() {
          count.value=++$counter;
     });
     $(".pre").click(function() {
         count.value=--$counter;
         
     });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="next">next</button>
 <button class="pre">pre</button>
 <input type="text" id="counter" value="0" />
```

Comment: why nest the click function inside the `count()` ? that doesn't sound correct.

Answer (score 0):

Your codes contain multiple errors. You reset the variable to 0 in your `count()` function, and put the `click()` function within the function.

```
var counter=0;
function count(){
    return counter;
}

$(".next-button").click(function() {
    counter = counter+1;
});
$(".previous").click(function() {
    counter = counter-1;
});

$('#counter').val(count());
// or 
$('#counter').val(counter);
```

I assume `$('#counter')` is a input text box.

p.s. Variable doesn't require to prefix with `$`. Extended [reading](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6209475/188331) about this Hungarian notation: when to use, when not to.

Answer (score 0):

First, your assign expression is run count function actually.

```
document.getElementById('counter').value =count();
```

The count function return 0.

```
(function() {
  var $counter = 0;

  var add = function() {
    $counter ++;
    setCounterValue();
  }

  var del = function() {
    $counter --;
    setCounterValue();  
  }

  var setCounterValue = function() {
    document.getElementById('counter').value = $counter;        
  }

  $(".next-button").bind("click", add);

  $(".previous").bind("click", del);
})()
```