# Create element from template element?

Tags: jquery

I'm having some trouble with this:

```
template = $("#template");
$(template).attr("id", "newid");

$(template).appendTo("body");
```

What I want to do is assign an id to the template, then amend the content. Trouble is, I am currently referring to the actual template element, and so the id is changing that. On using this template again, I cannot select as the id is different.

Any advice on optimal approach?

Comment: Not entirely sure what you what you mean? If you want to create an element from another, perhaps you want to use jQuery's `clone()` method? http://api.jquery.com/clone/.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Clone the object:

```
template = $("#template").clone();
template.attr("id","newid");
template.appendTo("body");
```

Comment: but then it creates a new node of type ´template´. I just wanted its body.

Comment: I think Manuel's version was what you were looking for. I also don't understand why would the template need to be cloned, but not its content.

Answer (score 17):

The HTML5 provides a `template` element:

```
contents = $('#template').html();
copy = $('<div id="copy"></div>');
$('body').append(copy.append(contents));
```

The HTML part:

```
<html>
  <body>
    <template id='template'>
    </template>
  </body>
</html>
```

The `clone` method is not sufficient.

Answer (score 11):

Three more notes on your code:

- You should use var [when declaring variable](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Values,_variables,_and_literals#Declaring_variables)
- [Consider prefixing variables storing jQuery objects with a dollar sign](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/205853/why-would-a-javascript-variable-start-with-a-dollar-sign)
- After you assigned a jQuery object to your variable, you shouldn't do it again.

So your code will look like:

```
var $template = $("#template").clone();
$template.attr("id", "newid");

$template.appendTo("body");
```

Comment: Because creating jQuery object is a lot of work under the hood(you can take a look in jQuery source) and why do it again, if you already done it and store result in variable? And even if it wasn't so much work, even if it's only cache reading, simply referring what variable already stores is always faster than anything else.

Answer (score 9):

For me `clone()` didn't work with `<template>`. Best answer was the one from Manuel, but to generate a jQuery object from template without adding an element as he did, I used this one-liner:

```
var template = $($("#template").html());
```

with this HTML:

```
<html>
 <body>
  <template id='template'>
  </template>
 </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the clone() method like so:

```
template = $('#template').clone();
template.attr('id', 'newid');
template.appendTo('body');
```

Look at http://api.jquery.com/clone/ for more info.

Comment: `template` is already a jQuery object. Don't pass it again to jQuery.

Answer (score 2):

The 3-lines solution will work, but I suggest the 1-line short jQuery style solution:

```
$('#template').clone().attr('id', 'newid').appendTo('body');
```

Comment: That's great! Unfortunately, I'm making significant changes to the template in between cloning, and appending.