# Significance of $ in javascript library and other languages

Tags: javascript, programming-languages, naming-conventions

Famous javascript libraries,

1. jQuery
2. prototypejs
3. mootools
4. scriptaculous

all uses `$`. What's the significance of `$` ?

and also, even php uses it to declare variables. I am sure some other languages uses it too.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6847041/reading-a-javascript-script-why-so-many-dollar-signs http://stackoverflow.com/questions/205853/why-would-a-javascript-variable-start-with-a-dollar-sign http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3107543/what-is-the-symbol-used-for-in-javascript

Comment: The significance of `$` in JavaScript is that you can use it in your identifiers (variable names, parameters, etc.). Identifiers may consist of letters, digits, and the `$` and `_` characters.

Comment: @JoshLee, How did you search that ? I thought it would have been asked earlier but couldnt find it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's just a character that can be part of identifiers in JavaScript.  No special significance outside of the fact that it's distinctive-looking. It's easy to recognize when you're scanning over code.

Now, in other languages, it can (and does) mean all sorts of things. The term *sigil* has come into fashion when referring to "special" characters that have syntactic significance in a programming language, specifically as modifying the semantics of a reference to a variable. In JavaScript, I would not use that term for "$" because it doesn't mean anything in particular to the interpreter.

*edit* — as noted in a comment, "$" has a role in JavaScript regular expression syntax, but I wouldn't consider that related in any way to its use in variable names. (Maybe somebody would; I don't know.)

Comment: It does have a special meaning in JavaScript's RegExp grammar, though.

Comment: @ŠimeVidas oh yes, that's true - I'll add that (though it's of course a completely separate thing)

Comment: Strange ! everyone uses it . I thought there's some historical significance associated with it but couldnt find. I find it easier to type `$`

Answer (score 2):

In Javascript, $ is just another character that can be used in variables. jQuery decided to use that as a short name for the jQuery() function so it will take up less space. Identifiers may consist of letters, digits, and the $ and _ characters

In other languages:

Perl $ in front of a variable means scalar, @ means array, % means hash and & means function.
PHP $ means what follows is a variable which could be an object reference.
Commodore basic: a trailing $ means it is a string variable. (You didn't need to know that.)

In PHP and Perl, the syntax reveals the details of the identifier so the program is easier to follow. name() name[] $name(), etc. all mean different things which are obvious from the syntax.