# jquery elements, declared as variables

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to know the best practices when declaring jquery dom elements as variables. Any difference between

```
var div = $('div');
```

and

```
var $div = $('div');
```

besides better readability? Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why would a JavaScript variable start with a dollar sign?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/205853/why-would-a-javascript-variable-start-with-a-dollar-sign)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`$div` simply gives an indication to the reader of the code that it represents a jQuery object. So no, there is no difference besides that.

Comment: @downvoter: Care to elaborate on why you thought this answer deserved a downvote? Is something inaccurate?

Comment: How did you even notice a downvote on a ~7 months old thread? :) Also, im not the downvoter ;)

Answer (score 3):

There is no difference it will only indicate its a jQuery object. It is generally followed as a convention.