# How do I add input type "file" in a new row?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

When a user adds a row in a table, it should display the input "file" feature under the "Image" column for each row so that the user can select a file for each row. But it does not display the file input within the row when I add a row.

Below is the html code:

```
   <table id="qandatbl" border="1">
    <tr>
        <th class="image">Image</th>
    </tr>
    </table>
```

Below is jquery code

```
function insertQuestion(form) {   

        var $tr = $("<tr></tr>");
        var $image = $("<td class='image'></td>");

        function image(){

        var $this = $(this);
        var $imagefile = $("<input type='file' name='imageFile' id='imageFile' />").attr('name',$this.attr('name'))
                         .attr('value',$this.val())

            $image.append($imagefile);

        };

        $tr.append($image);
        $('#qandatbl').append($tr);


    }
```

Comment: You like PHP syntax? $variable is not necessary in javascript. `variable` (without $) is enough.

Comment: @Armin: It's a widely-adopted convention to prepend `$` to variable names when the name represents a jQuery object.

Comment: Oh! Never heard about this convention, but good to know ;-)

Comment: @Armin: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/205853/why-would-a-javascript-variable-start-with-a-dollar-sign

Comment: Hm okay. But this seems to be a "convention" which has been created unofficially, cause on the official jquery documentation all samples are without this convention.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your current snippets looks confusing. Try this: http://jsfiddle.net/66qAR/

```
<form id="idOfTheForm" action="?" method="post"> 
<table border="1">
    <tr>
        <th class="image">Image</th>
    </tr>
</table>
</form>
```

And this javascript:

```
function insertQuestion(form) {
    var imageField = $('<input />')
        .attr({
            type: 'file',
            name: 'imageFile',
            id: 'imageFile'
        });
    $(form).find('table').append($('<tr />').append(imageField));
}
insertQuestion($('#idOfTheForm'));
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't see a call to the inner function `image()` anywhere. More over why do you have an inner function like that? Fixing that will most likely fix your problem.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this, but my question is, what is `this`? Because you currently generate a function that is not used in any later actions, I currently removed that function but can't figure out what the `$(this).val()` would result.

Also you pass a `form` param but don't use it?

```
 function insertQuestion(form) {   

    var $tr = $("<tr></tr>");
    var $image = $("<td class='image'></td>");


    var $imagefile = $("<input type='file' name='imageFile' id='imageFile' />").attr('name',$this.attr('name'))
                     .attr('value',$(this).val())
                     .appendTo($image);


    $tr.append($image);
    $('#qandatbl').append($tr);

}
```