# Javascript "$" meaning before a variable or namespace

Tags: javascript

Anybody knows what is the meaning of the $ sign before an object attribute.

For example:
 pages.$page

I've seen in some javascript codes and I'm not sure if it using some kind of framework.

I've used something like this (this.$el) to access to cached element in Backbone.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `$` within variable name is quite valid, so maybe `this` contains property names `$el`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why would a JavaScript variable start with a dollar sign?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/205853/why-would-a-javascript-variable-start-with-a-dollar-sign)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many people use  `$varName` to indicate that it is a `jQuery` variable/property

```
var $divs = $('div');
var nonJqueryVar = 'hello';
```

Comment: Thx Juan, I think that it could be a good use to highlight the difference. In this code they use jquery templates, so could be a good name convention. Thkx All !

Answer (score 8):

As far as javascript is concerned, `$` is just another character at the beginning of a variable name, at the end of a variable name, in the middle or all by itself.

As far as some frameworks are concerned like jQuery, it's a character that the framework uses in a specific way (by convention, not because it means anything special to javascript).

For example, in jQuery `$(selector)` is one of the main functions in jQuery and as such it is a popular convention to assign the resulting jQuery object to a variable with a $ in it like this:

```
var resetButton$ = $("#reset");
```

This convention then indicates to the reader that the variable contains a jQuery object.

Other frameworks also use the `$` sign, some in similar ways, some in other ways, but in all cases, it's just another character in javascript, but because it stands out, it's often used as a meaningful convention.

Once you become familiar with one of these types of conventions, it can make code a lot easier to read and your brain can actually recognize the meaning of the code even quicker with common, learned conventions.  But, these conventions of naming variables a certain way are completely optional.

Answer (score 2):

It is used to mark an element or object as a jQuery object (usually). It's a perfectly valid variable name though.