# JavaScript function what is scope and why using $

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [Why would a JavaScript variable start with a dollar sign?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/205853/why-would-a-javascript-variable-start-with-a-dollar-sign)

I am not sure what `$scope` and `$defer` are but they just seem to work.

```
function xyz($scope, $defer) {
    xyz = this;
    this.defer = $defer;
    this.scope = $scope;
    this.scope.test = function(re) {
        console.log(this,arguments);
    }
}
```

Comment: Looks strange anyway. xyz replaced by *this*, no use of function test. Is this really the complete code

Comment: @stefanbachert I'm guessing this is the sanitized version of some code encountered at work.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Generally these days devs name a variable `$something` to flag that it is an object type of a wrapping framework. For example, to cache a jQuery object, it makes sense to use `$this = $(this);`

That being said, there's nothing special about the dollar sign. Just a heads up for devs.

A bit of history and reasoning; ECMAScript 3 says:

> The dollar sign ($) and the underscore (_) are permitted anywhere in
>   an identifier. **The dollar sign is intended for use only in
>   mechanically generated code**.

Whereas ECMAScript 5 says:

> The dollar sign ($) and the underscore (_) are permitted anywhere in
>   an IdentifierName.

So when someone says "Hey you're not supposed to use a dollar sign in your var cuz it's for MECHANICALLY-GENERATED code!" you can say "Psh, ECMA 5, hello?"

Answer (score 5):

Those are names of parameters.

UPDATE: `$` is perfectly valid (even by itself, which is probably more common thanks to certain JS libraries) as an identifier in JavaScript, but it isn't usually used as a sigil like this. I'm guessing the code was written by somebody with too much Perl experience, or possibly somebody who mostly deals with jQuery-based code.

Comment: Or PHP even. I've caught myself doing it a couple times in the past.

Comment: Ive done it with variables that point to query object as a way to differentiate them. A practice I picked up while learning and it sort of stuck.

Comment: @AlienWebguy Heh. I try to pretend that PHP doesn't exist, but a very good point ;-)

Comment: @pdizz I don't write enough jQuery-based code for that to have come up as an issue for me, but if I were intermingling non-query objects with query objects often enough, that might be a nice way to help my future self figure out what is going on.

Comment: @HankGay Oops. I meant 'jquery objects' not 'query objects' but yeah it's more organization and personal preference than anything