# Do I need to put a dollar before variable names with javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following code:

```
var formSubmitHandler = function (link, form) {

    //e.preventDefault();
    var $form = form;
    var val = $form.valid();
    var action = $(form).data('action');
    var entity = $(form).data('entity');
```

Do I need the line "var $form = form"?  Can I just later on do "var val = form.valid(); ?

It's not my code so I am wondering why the developer added the $ before the form and assigned it?

**Update:**

Thanks for all your replies. If as has been said it's just to indicate that it's a jQuery variable then could I just remove that line by changing the function parameters to (link, $form) ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why would a JavaScript variable start with a dollar sign?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/205853/why-would-a-javascript-variable-start-with-a-dollar-sign)

Comment: Sometimes, the `$` before a variable name is to indicate that it is a jQuery object and not, say, a raw DOM element. That is, you might say `var $this = $(this)` with the `$` in front to indicate that it's a jQuery object. On the other hand, you might have `var element = document.getElementById('test')`. It's all up to the developer, of course.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`$` and `jQuery` are basically the jQuery instance.

It's good to understand that `$( < place something here >)` is a jQuery function call and `$your_variable_name` is just a variable with a dollar.

Some people use `$` in their own variables to indicate that it is a jQuery object. With this naming convention, your source code would like this.

```
var formSubmitHandler = function (link, form) {
    var $form = $(form);
    var val = $form.valid();
    var action = $form.data('action');
    var entity = $form.data('entity');
```

Comment: `Some people use $ in their own variables to indicate that it is a jQuery object.` just to note that it's used also in plain JS to indicate it's an HTMLElement reference.

Comment: I think it is very important to point out that `$` is not a jQuery thing.  It is used by jQuery...often.

Answer (score 3):

No, you don't have to use the `$` sign. It's just an aesthetic choice usually.

In your example code above, the function's argument is named form `function (link, form)`. Inside the function, the new variable being declared has a `$` to it so as to distinguish it from the argument variable `form`.

Answer (score 3):

That is not neccessary. The dollar sign before a variable is most of the times used as an indication it is a JQuery variable. JQuery uses the dollar sign as a shortcut. Using it in a variable name has no extra meaning other than the aesthetic meaning for the developer that it is a JQuery object.

Comment: To clarify for others: The dollar sign *is* the variable.

Answer (score 0):

It has become best practice to use the $ sign to help you distinguish between Javascript variables representing regular DOM elements (and every other data type) and variables that hold a reference to a jQuery object. For the latter you use the $ sign.