# History.js replaces the wrong content

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, browser-history, history.js

I have the following initiation in my JavaScript; I’m always using the code shown in github by the way. The full code can be [seen here](https://raw.github.com/gist/854622/ajaxify-html5.js)

```
var
        /* Application Specific Variables */
        contentSelector = '.tab-content,.page-content,article:first,.article:first,.post:first',
        $content = $(contentSelector).filter(':first'),
        contentNode = $content.get(0),
        $menu = $('#menu,#nav-sub,.nav,.nav-sub:first').filter(':first'),
        activeClass = 'active selected current youarehere open',
        activeSelector = '.active,.selected,.current,.youarehere, .open',
        menuChildrenSelector = '> li,> ul > li',
        /* Application Generic Variables */
        $body = $(document.body),
        rootUrl = History.getRootUrl(),
        scrollOptions = {
            duration: 800,
            easing:'swing'
        };
```

The problem lies in :

```
contentSelector = '.tab-content,.page-content,article:first,.article:first,.post:first',
```

and in:

```
$menu = $('#menu,#nav-sub,.nav,.nav-sub:first').filter(':first'),
```

When the menu clicked in `.nav`, has to change the `.page-content`.

When the menu is clicked in `.nav-sub`, the content has to be replaced in `.tab-content`

The problem is, both menu's change `.page-content`, instead of just either tab-content or page-content.

Any idea how to change this?

Comment: Please don't use $ for variables, it's just bad practice, especially if you also use jQuery.

Comment: Check the github link, i used the code from there. But will think about it in a later stage.

Comment: @VahurRoosimaa It is very common for people to prefix variables pointing to `jQuery` objects with a `$`. It is your personal preference not to do it, it has nothing to do with the question at hand.

Comment: @VahurRoosimaa have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/a/205974/63094 . Dollar sign ($)'s are permitted anywhere in variable names.

Answer (score 1):

Fix your content select

Change from

```
contentSelector = '.tab-content,.page-content,article:first,.article:first,.post:first'
```

TO

```
contentSelector = '.tab-content, .page-content, .article:first, .post:first'
```

Answer (score 0):

History.js isn't replacing the wrong content; ajaxify-html5.js (the script you are using) is doing exactly as it was designed:

- If the user clicks on an internal link (and the link does not have the `no-ajaxy` class), then the script intercepts the click, stops the browser from loading the page, and initiates an Ajax request for the page.

  Note that this includes all internal links on the page, not just ones in the menu.
- When the Ajax request is complete, the script replaces the content on the current page with the content from the response (and does some other clever things like set the `activeClass` on the right menu item, update the page title and run scripts from the response).

  The script uses the first element found with `contentSelector` as the "content" node. This does not depend on which link the user clicked on.

---

If you want to "ajaxify" only menu links, you can change (line 95):

```
$body.ajaxify();
```

to call `.ajaxify()` on your menu element instead.

If you want to update a different element with the new content, you can change (line 145):

```
$content.html(contentHtml).ajaxify().css('opacity',100).show(); /* you could fade in here if you'd like */
```

to update another element instead.