# Find element by id

Tags: jquery

everyone! I did this:

```
$('#kill').live('click',function(){
   $closeId = $(this).parent().attr('id');
   $('#suggested').find('#' + $closeId).removeClass().addClass('active');
});
```

and it doesn't work. I tried to test it:

```
var $test = $('#suggested').find('#' + $closeId).length;
```

and it's return '0', it's incorrect. It would be great if you know how to fix it.

Thanks!

Comment: why are you calling your variables `$var` this isn't php...

Comment: @Jakub ~ personally, I don't use that convention, but I've seen it used to "mark" variables referencing jQuery objects (as opposed to, I guess, DOM elements maybe?).

Comment: @Jakub - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/205853/why-would-a-javascript-variable-start-with-a-dollar-sign

Comment: Why are you using `find` ? Do you have duplicated `ID`s ? It should be unique.

Answer (score 3):

Do

```
$('#kill').live('click',function(){
   $(this).parent().removeClass().addClass('active');
});
```

Notes :

- You don't have to get the id if you just want the element.
- Don't use `find` if you have the id. As you can only have one element with a given id in a document, the most efficient is to use `$('#' + $closeId)`.
- with new jQuery versions, don't use [live](http://api.jquery.com/live/) but [on](http://api.jquery.com/on/).

Comment: thanks for reply. Let me explain: i have 2 div's and one input for tags; #kill removing current tag from input and i whant make this tag visible/active in both div's again. And yes - current tag has same id in all cases.