# What is this kind of variable $variable

Tags: javascript, variables

I found an JavaScript file in a website using a variable like this:

```
var $variable
```

What kind is it?
Thanks, DGM

Comment: It's nothing special but maybe it use jquery and indicate that the value is jquery object, I use variables like that in my code.

Comment: See **[this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/553734/1626250)** to **[this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/205853/why-would-a-javascript-variable-start-with-a-dollar-sign)**.

Comment: JavaScript doesn't have "kinds" of variables.

Answer (score 3):

`$` is a regular symbol like any other legal one in JS and can be used as or part of a variable as well:

```
var $ = {};
```

It's also the identifier for the [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) object. So that's why you'll normally see variables named that way that represent jQuery objects:

```
var $variable = $('#element');
```

There's also [Underscore.js](http://underscorejs.org/#chain) that uses the underscore symbol `_` as its root object.

Answer (score 1):

It is a completely normal variable, starting with the dollar sign - which has no special meaning in JavaScript. It is a valid identifier just as like the underscore.

Sometimes, variable names prefixed with $ indicate that they contain an object wrapper created by one of the libraries that use `$` as a constructor (for example jQuery); in contrast to a "plain value".

Answer (score 0):

Javascript identifiers must start with a letter, an underscore or a dollar sign.  So it is just a variable.

The intended use of the $ sign was for code generators, but some libraries use it for their own purposes.

Answer (score 0):

It is perfectly valid to use $ in javascript variable names. Personally, I try to avoid this as it can be confused with jquery objects or php variables which may have crept into the javascript by mistake.