# jQuery duplicate DIV into another DIV

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Need some jquery help copying a DIV into another DIV and hoping that this is possible. I have the following HTML:

```
  <div class="container">
  <div class="button"></div>
  </div>
```

And then I have another DIV in another location in my page and I would like to copy the 'button' div into the following 'package' div:

```
<div class="package">

Place 'button' div in here

</div>
```

Answer (score 204, accepted):

You'll want to use the `clone()` method in order to get a deep copy of the element:

```
$(function(){
  var $button = $('.button').clone();
  $('.package').html($button);
});
```

Full demo: http://jsfiddle.net/3rXjx/

From the [jQuery docs](http://api.jquery.com/clone/):

> The .clone() method performs a deep copy of the set of matched
>   elements, meaning that it copies the matched elements as well as all
>   of their descendant elements and text nodes. When used in conjunction
>   with one of the insertion methods, .clone() is a convenient way to
>   duplicate elements on a page.

Comment: This does not keep values added by the user on inputs.

Comment: can you please tell me why we need `$` in `var $button`. I believe in js you can declare var simply as `var button` .

Comment: @KNU It's not necessary but it's a common convention in the jQuery world. It indicates that the $button variable is a jQuery object. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/205853/why-would-a-javascript-variable-start-with-a-dollar-sign

Comment: You are using a jQuery object as input argument to the html method. Reading jQuery's documentation of html(), that method takes either nothing, a HTML string or a function as input. Please explain why your solution works. Thanks!

Answer (score 26):

Copy code using clone and appendTo function :

Here is also working example [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sunnysm/fwjh1mv5/1/)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="copy"><a href="http://brightwaay.com">Here</a> </div>
<br/>
<div id="copied"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){
        $('#copy').clone().appendTo('#copied');
    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 4):

You can copy your div like this

```
$(".package").html($(".button").html())
```

Answer (score 2):

Put this on an event

```
$(function(){
    $('.package').click(function(){
       var content = $('.container').html();
       $(this).html(content);
    });
});
```