# How to move the google autocomplete whole div into another div

Tags: php, jquery, html, css

I need to move the Google Autocomplete whole div into another div.

My div structure:

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<div class="container">
   <div class="row">
      some contents 
   <div> 
  <div class="pac-container">
    auto complete content 
  </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Now I need to move the `.pac-container` class before row class  due to my design issue. How can fix this.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16068047/jquery-duplicate-div-into-another-div

Answer (score 1):

This is how I would do it:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".pac-container").detach().insertBefore($(".row"));
});
```

[Here is the **JSFiddle** demo](https://jsfiddle.net/Lx23mr20/)

Basically it detaches the element from the DOM structure, and then inserts it before the *element* that matches the `row` class

Comment: its not working. becaues my  .pac-container content load dynamically.

Comment: Have a look at [this JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Lx23mr20/1/), the code waits for the content of the `.pac-container` class to finish loading before detaching and moving it. But even without it, it should normally work since ur ajax code should be setting the data received into the `.pac-container` container whenever it is. Can you provide more details please...?

Comment: on page load .pac-container  display none . When I change the address from one textbox .pac-container display.

Comment: I used above code, but  .pac-container not loaded before row class.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.row').insertAfter('.pac-container');
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to use the clone() method in order to get a deep copy of the element:

```
$(function(){ 
var $button = $('.button').clone();
  $('.package').html($button);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the pac-container is inserted dynamically, you have to listen for it to be inserted. Since you're using jQuery, here's a solution:

```
$(document).bind('DOMNodeInserted', function(e) {

  // Ignore dynamically-inserted scripts and other elements
  // since .pac-container is a div
  if (e.target.nodeName === 'DIV') {

    // Prioritizes the contained functions
    setTimeout(function() {
      var $el = $(e.target);
      if ($el.attr('class') === 'pac-container pac-logo') {
        self.cleanAutocomplete($el);
      }
    }, 0);
  }
});

// Remove bound events on document for performance
// and move .pac-container
function cleanAutocomplete($el) {
  $(document).unbind('DOMNodeInserted');
  $el.detach().insertBefore($('.row'));
};
```

I was trying to solve the same problem and this works for me. I'm using Backbone, so the `$(document).bind(...)` is contained within the function that's creating the autocomplete with `new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(...)`.

The main thing to watch out for here is that you'll probably have multiple instances of `.row` so you should probably give it a unique class or ID.

Hope that helps!