# How to copy/clone div to corresponding structure in other container

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

What is the best way to copy/clone a div inside a list of divs with jquery to the corresponding locations in another container.

I try to copy all "copy-this" elements to the same location in the other container. So first ".copy-this" should be duplicated in the first item of the second container, same for (2)->(2) etc...

HTML DOM:

```
<div class="content">
    <div class="item">
        <div class="copy-this">Some info</div>
        <div class="random-div">Not to copy</div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        <div class="copy-this">Some info 2</div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        <div class="copy-this">Some info 3</div>
        <div class="random-div">Not to copy</div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        <div class="copy-this">Some info 4</div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="content">
    <div class="item"> 
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        <div class="random-div">Not to copy</div>   
    </div>
    <div class="item">      
    </div>
    <div class="item">      
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: `nth-selectors` don't care about class, only tag names like `a`, `div`, `section`, etc. and an elements position relative to it's siblings.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery duplicate DIV into another DIV](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16068047/jquery-duplicate-div-into-another-div)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**EDIT**

OP has requested the behavior under the condition of viewport size (window width) being that the clones are present when at 600px or less.

> How would you use this functions inside a responsive function, to copy it if the window loads/resizes under 600px, and remove it if it resizes to over 600px again? If i wrap it in this: `$(window).on("load resize",function(e){ if ($(window).width() < 1200) { } });` It keeps firing for each resize.

While this should be another question entirely, I have added this solution in reply to OP's comment/question. The following [<kbd>**PLUNKER**</kbd>](https://embed.plnkr.co/f6JPqSN5ecsiFyKDGtwt/) uses one media query and the extra styles are for demonstration purposes only. The relevant addition is one media query with one ruleset:

> ```
> @media (min-width:600px) {
>   .content + .content > .item > .copy-this {
>     display: none;
>   }
> }
> ```

---

**ORIGINAL ANSWER**

First we collect all `.copy-this` with [**`.each()`**](http://api.jquery.com/each/) method:

> ```
> $('.copy-this').each(function(idx, obj) {
> ```

Next, we need to differentiate the 2 `.content` divs in order to designate which one we need to clone the content from and which one to append the clones to (without modifying layout assuming that a criterion), we can use the [***adjacent sibling selector*** **`+`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_selectors). With a solid hook into the target elements we will append to, we'll use [**`.eq(idx)`**](http://api.jquery.com/eq/) to sync the `.item`s from the first `.content`, to the `.item`s of the last `.content`.

> ```
> var target = $('.content + .content > .item').eq(idx);
> ```

Finally, we [**`.clone()`**](http://api.jquery.com/clone/) and [**`.prepend()`**](http://api.jquery.com/prepend/). Note the results in that the clones are highlighted with yellow text on black background.

> ```
> var clone = $(this).clone(true, true);
> target.prepend(clone);
> ```

**SNIPPET**

```js
    $('.copy-this').each(function(idx, obj) {
      var target = $('.content + .content > .item').eq(idx);
      var clone = $(this).clone(true, true);
      target.prepend(clone);
    });
```

```css
.content + .content > .item > .copy-this {
  color: yellow;
  background: black;
}
.random-div {
  color: brown;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>
  <div class="content">
    <div class="item">
      <div class="copy-this">Some info 1[#1]</div>
      <div class="random-div">Not to copy 1[#1]</div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <div class="copy-this">Some info 2[#1]</div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <div class="copy-this">Some info 3[#1]</div>
      <div class="random-div">Not to copy 2[#1]</div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <div class="copy-this">Some info 4[#1]</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    <div class="item">
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <div class="random-div">This is original content[#2]</div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
    </div>
    <div class="item">
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: `,content ~ .content` will target all `.content` after the first one.  Or `body > div:nth-of-type(3)`. Or `.content + .content + .content`. The trick is targeting the destination not so much as to where you came from. Coming from the 1st or the 2nd, etc. can be stored in a var beforehand.

Comment: Well, you kinda already answered your own question: `"$(window).width() < 1200) { } }); It keeps firing for each resize."` Indeed it will because it's saying onresize if the window is **less than 1200px** make a batch of clones. Then you ask me the limit is under 600px what to do? That's what you do: cut 1200 down to 600 and it won't clone as much when you resize since it's more common to resize windows between 640 to 960. See this: [Plunker](http://embed.plnkr.co/va9GQkx4ZQMBsrDnROfB/)

Comment: See edit, and if these answers have resolved your problems, click the green ✔.

Answer (score 2):

Try to loop through first div then insert outerHTML of copy-this into second container

```js
var content1 = document.getElementsByClassName('content')[0],
    content1Items = content1.getElementsByClassName('item'),
    content2 = document.getElementsByClassName('content')[1],
    content2Items = content2.getElementsByClassName('item'),
    copiedHTML;

for (var i = 0, l = content1Items.length; i < l; i++) {
    copiedHTML = content1Items[i].getElementsByClassName('copy-this')[0].outerHTML;

    content2Items[i].insertAdjacentHTML('afterbegin', copiedHTML);
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
    <div class="item">
        <div class="copy-this">Some info</div>
        <div class="random-div">Not to copy</div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        <div class="copy-this">Some info 2</div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        <div class="copy-this">Some info 3</div>
        <div class="random-div">Not to copy</div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        <div class="copy-this">Some info 4</div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="content">
    <div class="item"> 
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        <div class="random-div">Not to copy</div>   
    </div>
    <div class="item">      
    </div>
    <div class="item">      
    </div>
</div>
```

### Jquery method

```js
var content1 = $('.content').eq(0),
    content2 = $('.content').eq(1),
    copiedHTML;

$.each(content1.find('.item'), function (i, item) {
  copiedHTML = $(item).find('.copy-this').clone();
  content2.find('.item').eq(i).prepend(copiedHTML);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="content">
    <div class="item">
        <div class="copy-this">Some info</div>
        <div class="random-div">Not to copy</div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        <div class="copy-this">Some info 2</div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        <div class="copy-this">Some info 3</div>
        <div class="random-div">Not to copy</div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        <div class="copy-this">Some info 4</div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="content">
    <div class="item"> 
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        <div class="random-div">Not to copy</div>   
    </div>
    <div class="item">      
    </div>
    <div class="item">      
    </div>
</div>
```