# I need to duplicate an existing HTML table on the parent page to the child pages

Tags: jquery, woocommerce, html-table

I have a table:

```html
<h2>Downloads</h2>
<table id="dw">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td><strong>Product Datasheet:</strong></td>
<td>Datasheet</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

This table resides within my parent product in woocommerce on a custom tab that i have created.  Now, i want to duplicate this information into the tabs on each child product by referencing it somehow rather than recreating it.  I have researched and it seams that some from of jquery is the way to go but it gives no instructions on how to recreate the ENTIRE table.

Some people are saying that they used a link to link back to the "parent product" tab. but i don't want to do that. i want an exact duplicate to show on the child page this way when information changes i only have to change it in one location rather than 300 for each child.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery duplicate DIV into another DIV](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16068047/jquery-duplicate-div-into-another-div)

Comment: Also here:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/921290/is-it-possible-to-clone-html-element-objects-in-javascript-jquery/921302

Comment: What do you mean by parent/child pages? In WooCommerce the only product that'd have a parent is a variation (with a variable product being the parent), however, they share the same page.

Comment: Grouped products also share a parent/child relationship: the top level page where you insert the other products in the grouping would be the parent.