# Declaring variables javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I just have a quick question and cant find anything on google. I was going through some code another programmer put together and he declares ALL of his javascript variables with $ in front of them...for instance:

```
 var $secondary;
```

Is there a reason for this? Could this cause problems in the future if JQuery ever ends up being used. I'm just curious because I was going to clean it up if so.

Comment: Have a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/553734/1650716

Comment: Take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/205853/why-would-a-javascript-variable-start-with-a-dollar-sign

Comment: That must be painful to see every variable prefixed with a $.

Comment: haha just a bit :P Thanks everyone for clearing that up!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use this convention too keep track of if a variable is storing a JQuery object. So say the function `getJQueryObject()` returns a JQuery object and I want to store it.

i.e:

```
var $myJQobj = getJQueryObject();
```

Makes it clear that `$myJQobj` is a JQuery object unlike i.e

```
var myStr = "hello";
```

The `$` as the first character in the identifier doesn't have any special meaning, you aren't invoking a method like `$()`, it's just a perfectly valid identifier in JavaScript. But the factthat the `$` is used in JQuery makes what I was talking about before even clearer.

Answer (score 2):

> Is there a reason for this?

Hard to say. Maybe he came from a PHP background where `$` prefixes the variables. Maybe he's a jQuery addict. Who knows? You'd have to ask him. That aside, `$` is a perfectly legitimate character to use in a JavaScript variable name but as you noted, it could cause issues with jQuery. But that's why jQuery offers a [`noConflict()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/) option.

Comment: how you can get a confilct if you dont use asing `$` to a function or value?

Comment: Why would it cause a conflict? That's like saying `apple` will conflict with a variable named `a`.

Comment: Ok, I re-worded that part of my answer.

Comment: I still see "it could cause issues with jQuery" in your answer.

Comment: @icktoofay - by issues I mean if the OP ever decides to add jQuery to this project, it may cause undue confusion when debugging or troubleshooting. Merely having a variable with `$` wouldn't be a specific problem.

Comment: Oh, I see. I'd still reword it to be clearer that it wouldn't cause technical difficulties but rather cause confusion.

Answer (score 1):

`$` is a valid variable character, and in PHP all variables start with it. It's possibe that that particular developer uses `$` as a "flag" to mean "this is a variable". It has no special meaning.

Answer (score 1):

`$` just a character that you can use in a variable name. Some people like to use it to denote variables that contain jQuery objects:

```
var $foo = $('#foo');
var bar = 42;
```

But that's just a personal preference. It has no special meaning.

Answer (score 1):

its just a convention for jQuery DOM selctions.

```
var $logo = $('a.logo');
```

it wont cause any issues - it just lets other devs know that you're working with a jQuery wrapped dom element.

Answer (score 0):

$ is fine for use in JavaScript.  PHP uses the same variable syntax so maybe he was used to it from that.