# $ issue as prefix jquery variable names

Tags: javascript, jquery, visual-studio-2010

I was going through the following post [Why would a JavaScript variable start with a dollar sign?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/205853/why-would-a-javascript-variable-start-with-a-dollar-sign) where it is suggested to use $ as a prefix for variable name which represent to jQuery objects.

```
var $email = $("#email");
```

I have no issue in respect to naming convention here but the issue is that I can't select the whole variable by double clicking it. I do copy the variable very often and paste it over the js file to make use of it. But when I double click it in Visual Studio only "email" portion is selected which is kind of frustrating experience, even in the browser only "email" is selected. How to overcome this situation?

Comment: you know... you don't have to follow that convention if it's such an annoyance...

Answer (score 0):

In jQuery this sign $ means alias for function name 'jQuery'. And here $email just a name of value and my opinion this is not good name.

Comment: Except that it's not the name of a value, it's the name of a jQuery object that has a collection of zero or one DOM elements. Using `$` on the variable name helps separate those variables that are jQuery objects from those that aren't, IMO.

Comment: Personally i think it's helpful if you use jQuery heavily. Much easier to keep track of which objects are jQuery objects and which are normal htmlElement objects this way.

Answer (score 0):

Holding CTRL+SHIFT will select it with two double clicks, select email first and then $.

Answer (score 0):

Conventions are to make life easier in the long run. If that does not makes your life easier, then don't follow it. You can prefix them with something more friendly to Visual Studio and still be clear, for example `jq` would be a good choice.